# List of primes under a million

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, primes

This is my first code golf question, and a very simple one at that, so I apologise in advance if I may have broken any community guidelines.

The task is to print out, in ascending order, all of the prime numbers less than a million. The output format should be one number per line of output.

The aim, as with most code golf submissions, is to minimise code size. Optimising for runtime is also a bonus, but is a secondary objective.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but it is essentially just primality testing, which is a component of a number of existing questions (e.g. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5087 , http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1977 ). FWIW, one guideline which isn't followed enough (even by people who should know better) is to pre-propose a question in the meta sandbox http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/423 for criticism and discussion of how it can be improved before people start answering it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was worried about this question being too similar to the plethora of prime number-related questions already around.

Comment: In all those solutions that spell out "1000000", why not run to 999999 instead of 1000000, saves a byte.  Everyone knows that 1000000 is not prime.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Because `10^6` is even shorter ;)

Comment: A few years back I submitted an IOCCC entry that prints primes with only 68 characters in C -- unfortunately it stops well short of a million, but it might be of interest to some: http://computronium.org/ioccc.html

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs How about `1e6` :-D

Answer (score 42):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
k=P=1
while k<1e6:P%k>0==print(k);P*=k*k;k+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9s2wNaQqzwjMydVIdvGMNXMKkA1287A1ragKDOvRCNb0zpAyzZbK9s6W9vW8P9/AA)

By the time the loop reaches testing `k`, it has iteratively computed the squared-factorial `P=(k-1)!^2`. If `k` is prime, then it doesn't appear in the product `1 * 2 * ... * (k-1)`, so it's not a factor of `P`. But, if it's composite, all its prime factors are smaller and so in the product. The squaring is only actually needed to stop `k=4` from falsely being called prime.

More strongly, it follows from [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) that when `k` is prime, `P%k` equals `1`. Though we only need that it's nonzero here, it's useful in general that `P%k` is an indicator variable for whether `k` is prime.

Thanks to @Sisyphus for 1 byte with `P%k>0==print(k)` using chained operator short-circuiting in place of `P%k and print(k)`.

Comment: You can save a byte doing `P%k>0==print(k)` instead of `P%k and print(k)`.

Comment: @Sisyphus Great find, and on an answer that's had many eyes on it! Well worth an [outgolfing bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/20260). Is there an answer of yours I can bounty for this? You could also post this improvement as an answer here, or post an answer here in another language.

Comment: I've posted a [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211895/48931), since I'd prefer the improvement stays in your (highly visible) post (and you did 99% of the work with Wilson's theorem!).

Answer (score 33):

#### *Mathematica*, <s>17</s> 24

Just for comparison:

```
Prime@Range@78498
```

*As noted in a comment I failed to provide one prime per line; correction:*

```
Column@Prime@Range@78498
```

Comment: `Prime~Array~78498` also 17 :)

Comment: Would be nine bytes in mthmca, if that were to be released.

Comment: That violates the condition of one prime per line of output. Prefixing with `Print/@` and terminating with `;` to prevent output of a long list of `Null`s fixes that, at the cost of 8 extra characters.

Comment: @celtschk I don't know if I missed or disregarded that five years ago.

Comment: Well, I definitely missed that it was from five years ago :-)

Answer (score 26):

### C, 61 chars

Almost exactly the same as [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5818/3544) (the question is almost exactly the same too).

```
n=2;main(m){n<1e6&&main(m<2?printf("%d\n",n),n:n%m?m-1:n++);}
```

Comment: Got `SEG-FAULT` after printing `881`

Comment: @Manav, perhaps you compiled without optimizations. It relies on a good optimizer, which will remove the recursion.

Comment: Yes adding `-O3` to `gcc` solved the problem!!

Comment: This method is insane. I love it.

Comment: I can get you to 57 bytes `n=2;main(m){n<1e6&&main(m<2?printf("%d\n",n),n:m-++n%m);}`

Comment: Since `n%m?m-1:n++` can be shortened to `m-++n%m`. Subtracting the conditional while nesting the increment in the conditional logic itself removes the need for the ternary operation! :D

Comment: Looks nice, but unfortunately 13 is prime and 33 isn't.

Answer (score 23):

#### MATLAB <strike>(16)</strike> (12)

Unfortunately, this outputs on a single line:

```
primes(1000000)
```

but that is solved by a simple matrix transpose:

```
primes(1000000)'
```

and I can cut out some characters by using exponential notation (as suggested in the comments):

```
primes(1e6)'
```

Comment: Using `1e6` instead of `1000000` helps here too.

Comment: @orion That would make it 11 characters

Comment: @Axoren that does not include the `'` at the end

Answer (score 20):

### Bash (37 chars)

```
seq 2 1e6|factor|sed 's/.*: //g;/ /d'
```

### (60 chars)

```
seq 2 1000000|factor|sed -e 's/[0-9]*: //g' -e '/^.* .*$/ d'
```

on my computer (2.0 GHz cpu, 2 GB ram) takes 14 seconds.

Comment: This can be improved to:
    `seq 2 1000000|factor|sed 's/[0-9]*: //g;/^.* .*$/ d'`

Comment: yes you're  right. I wrote my sed command clean, not golfed :P

Comment: This can also further be improved to: `seq 2 1000000|factor|sed 's/[0-9]*: //g;/ /d'`

Comment: I was applying this improvement before I saw your comment ;)

Comment: `awk` is faster and shorter in filtering this: `seq 2 1000000|factor|awk '!$3&&$0=$2'` – 37 characters. Or if you filter out the 1 case with `awk`, but the code's length is the same: `seq 1000000|factor|awk 'NF==2&&$0=$2'`.

Comment: Yes, that awk script is about 25% faster :)

Comment: `seq 1e6|factor|awk '$0=$2*!$3'` is a bit shorter.

Comment: seq, factor and sed are external programs, this may as well be `c p` where c is a symlink to cat and p is a text file with primes up to a million... can you do it with shell builtins?

Comment: @technosaurus `seq` and `factor` are in `coreutils`, so it's legitimate. `sed` is also pretty ubiquitous.

`coreutils` can be treated like a built-in. Bash without coreutils is like C++ without the STL.

Answer (score 16):

### J, 21 characters

```
1[\p:i.(_1 p:1000000)
```

which can be shortened to

```
1[\p:i.78498
```

if you know how many primes there are below 1000000.

Comment: Using enfile items, `,.`, instead of 1[\\ to save a character. Remove the unnecessary parenthesis, and use exponential notation: `1e6`.

Comment: Came up with this: `,.i.&.(p:^:_1)1e6` Not shorter (after applying @Omar 's suggestions) but I found the use of under interesting.

Answer (score 11):

## Bash, 30 bytes

Since [saeedn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/3115) won't act on my suggestion – which is both shorter and faster than his approach – I thought I'd post my own answer:

```
seq 1e6|factor|awk '$0=$2*!$3'
```

#### How it works

```
seq 1e6
```

lists all positive integers up to 1,000,000.

```
factor
```

factors them one by one. For the first ten, the output is the following:

```
1:
2: 2
3: 3
4: 2 2
5: 5
6: 2 3
7: 7
8: 2 2 2
9: 3 3
10: 2 5
```

Finally,

```
awk '$0=$2*!$3'
```

changes the entire line (`$0`) to the product of the second field (the first prime factor) and the logical negation of the third field (`1` if the is one prime factor or less, `0` otherwise).

This replaces lines corresponding to prime numbers with the number itself and all other lines with zeros. Since awk only prints truthy values, only prime number will get printed.

Comment: `awk '$0=$2*!$3'` is awksome cool!

Answer (score 10):

## PowerShell, <strike>47</strike> 44 bytes

Very slow, but the shortest I could come up with.

```
$p=2..1e6;$p|?{$n=$_;!($p-lt$_|?{!($n%$_)})}
```

## PowerShell, 123 bytes

This is much faster; far from optimal, but a good compromise between efficiency and brevity.

```
 $p=2..1e6;$n=0
 while(1){$p=@($p[0..$n]|?{$_})+($p[($n+1)..($p.count-1)]|?{$_%$p[$n]});$n++;if($n-ge($p.count-1)){break}}
 $p
```

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby 34

```
require'prime';p Prime.take 78498
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3.x: 66 chars

```
for k in range(2,10**6):
 if all(k%f for f in range(2,k)):print(k)
```

## More efficient solution: 87 chars

Based on the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
p=[];z=range(2,10**6)
while z:f=z[0];p+=[f];z=[k for k in z if k%f]
for k in p:print(k)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 51

```
mapM print [n|n<-[2..10^6],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]]
```

Comment: You can change `mapM_` to `mapM`, return value won't be printed, and this is Code Golf. ;)

Comment: why are there extra spaces after print and in (> 0)?

Comment: You can replace 999999 with 10^6. And please update your byte count - 63 can't possibly be right.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, 37

Will golf more, if I can...

Most of this is trying to parse `factor`'s awkward output format.

```
seq 1e6|factor|grep -oP "(?<=: )\d+$"
```

Takes 5.7 or so seconds to complete on my machine.

(It just happened that *my* post was the *first* to go on the second page of answers, so nobody is going to see it...)

### Old solution

This is longer and slower (takes 10 seconds).

```
seq 1e6|factor|egrep ':.\S+$'|grep -oE '\S+$'
```

Comment: Wow - I never came across `factor` before, but there it is right there in coreutils!

Comment: Shave off one character: `seq 1e6|factor|grep -oP "(?<=: )\d+$"` with a perl-grep lookbehind

Comment: @DigitalTrauma how does that work

Comment: `-P` enables perl-style regexes.  `(?<=: )` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the string ": ".  Basically this says that ": " must come before what matches `\d+$`, but is not actually part of the match, so the `-o` option just gives us one matching number after the colon, i.e. just gives numbers where there is only one factor, i.e. prime.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma added

Answer (score 8):

#### Ruby <s>50</s> 41

```
require'mathn'
p (2..1e6).select &:prime?
```

Comment: No need for `.to_a`, as [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) already includes `select`. You can also use the shorthand notation for [Symbol#to_proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) to shorten it further: `p (2..1e6).select &:prime?` (1 is not prime)

Comment: @Ventero thanks a lot! I didn't know about the Symbol#to_proc. I gotta pay more attention to the shortcuts Ruby offers.

Comment: Shorter version `require'prime';p Prime.take 78498`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Great! I think that's so different that you can post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Good use of some good ol' country boy mathn'

Comment: Shorter version (29 bytes) without lib: `p(2..1e6).select{_1/1||_1/_1}`

Answer (score 8):

### APL, 15

```
p~,p∘.×p←1↓⍳1e6
```

My interpreter ran into memory problems, but it works in theory.

Comment: How? Can you give a deskription?

Comment: You need a `⍪` in front to make one number per line, and you don't need the `,`.

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen `⍳` are the first integers. `1↓` drops the first one. `p←` assigns to p. `p∘.×p` makes a multiplication table. `p~` removes from p whatever is on the right. (`,` isn't needed, it ravels the table into a list.)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 49 bytes

Regular expression kung fu :)

```
for(1..1E6){(1x$_)=~/^(11+?)\1+$/ or print"$_\n"}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
for(1 .. 1_000_000) { 
    (1x$_) =~ /^(11+?)\1+$/ or print "$_\n";
}
```

It hasn't even made 10% progress while I type this post!

Source for the regex: http://montreal.pm.org/tech/neil_kandalgaonkar.shtml

Comment: inspired me to write a perl6 version. also, `1000000` can be written `10**6`

Comment: Also, 1000000 can be written 1E6

Comment: Always was a favorite regex of mine, but you need to remember that it fails spectacularly once you get to higher numbers - because of the fact that it's converting huge numbers into unary. This regex might not work for finding primes in the hundreds of thousands and beyond, depending on one's configuration of the language (and your machine.)

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 11

```
primes(10^6)
```

It looks like built ins are getting upvotes, plus I needed more words for longer answer.

Answer (score 7):

## J (15 or 9)

I can't believe this beat Mathematica (even if it's just <s>a single</s> by 2 chars)

```
a#~1 p:a=:i.1e6
```

Or:

```
p:i.78498
```

Comment: `... The output format should be one number per line of output.` That's why my answer begins with `1[\ `.

Answer (score 6):

## gs2, 5 bytes

Encoded in CP437:

```
∟)◄lT
```

`1C 29` pushes a million, `11 6C` is primes below, `54` is show lines.

Answer (score 5):

### C, <strike>91</strike> <strike>88</strike> <strike>85</strike> <strike>82</strike> <strike>81</strike> <strike>80</strike> <strike>76</strike> 72 characters

```
main(i,j,b){for(;i++<1e6;b++&&printf("%d\n",i))for(j=2;j<i;)b=i%j++&&b;}
```

The algorithm is terribly inefficient, but since we're doing code-golf that shouldn't matter.

Comment: you can shorten it easily:
`main(i,j,b){for(;i++<1e6;b++&&printf("%d\n",i))for(j=2;j<i;)b=i%j++&&b;}` or some idea like this (since I actually didn't compile it)

Comment: How is `i` sure to be 0? I think that, if you provide *any* argument, it'll fail. Also, I think `j` will have some sort of type error. Not sure for `b` though.

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript, 22/20 (20/19) bytes

```
n(6?,:|2>{(.p|%-.}do:n
```

At the cost of speed, the code can be made two bytes shorter:

```
n(6?,:|2>.{|%2>-}/n*
```

If the output format specified in the edited question is disregarded (which is what many of the existing answers do), two bytes can be saved in the fast version and one can be saved in the slow one:

```
n(6?,:|2>{(.p|%-.}do
n(6?,:|2>.{|%2>-}/`
```

This will print an additional LF after the primes for the fast version, and it will print the primes as an array for the slow one.

#### How it works

Both versions are implementations of the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

The fast version does the following:

1. Set `A = [ 2 3 4 … 999,999 ]` and `| = [ 0 1 2 … 999,999 ]`.
2. Set `N = A[0]` and print `N`.
3. Collect every N-th element from `|` in `C`. These are the multiples of `N`.
4. Set `A = A - C`.
5. If `A` is non-empty, go back to 2.

```
n(6?   # Push "\n".pop() ** 6 = 1,000,000.
,:|    # Push | = [ 0 1 2 … 999,999 ].
,2>    # Push A = [ 2 3 4 … 999,999 ].
{      #
  (    # Unshift the first element (“N”) of “A”.
  .p   # Print “N”.
  |%   # Collect every N-th element from “A” into a new array, starting with the first.
  -    # Take the set difference of “A” and the array from above.
  .    # Duplicate the set difference.
}do    # If the set difference is non-empty, repeat.
:n     # Store the empty string in “n”, so no final LF will get printed.
```

The slow version works in a similar fashion, but instead of successively removing multiples of the minimum of “A” (which is always prime), it removes multiples of all positive integers below 1,000,000.

#### Competitiveness

In absence of any built-in mathematical functions to factorize or check for primality, all GolfScript solutions will either be very large or very inefficient.

While still far from being efficient, I think I have achieved a decent speed-to-size ratio. At the time of its submission, this approach seems to be the shortest of those that do not use any of the aforementioned built-ins. I say *seems* because I have no idea how some of the answers work...

I've benchmarked all four submitted GolfScript solutions: [w0lf's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5987) (trial division), [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27063) (Wilson's theorem) and the two of this answer. These were the results:

```
Bound     | Trial division     | Sieve (slow)       | Wilson's theorem | Sieve (fast)
----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------
1,000     | 2.47 s             | 0.06 s             | 0.03 s           | 0.03 s
10,000    | 246.06 s (4.1 m)   | 1.49 s             | 0.38 s           | 0.14 s
20,000    | 1006.83 s (16.8 m) | 5.22 s             | 1.41 s           | 0.38 s
100,000   | ~ 7 h (estimated)  | 104.65 (1.7 m)     | 35.20 s          | 5.82 s
1,000,000 | ~ 29 d (estimated) | 111136.97s (3.1 h) | 3695.92 s (1 h)  | 418.24 s (7 m)
```

Comment: Is the "slow" sieve just a Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: Both are. The slow version is just an awful implementation.

Answer (score 5):

## NARS2000 APL, 7 characters

```
⍸0π⍳1e6
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Answer (score 4):

### Golfscript <s>26 25</s> 24

#### Edit (saved one more char thanks to Peter Taylor):

```
10 6?,{:x,{)x\%!},,2=},`
```

Old code:

```
10 6?,{.,{)\.@%!},,2=*},`
```

This code has only theoretical value, as it is incredibly slow and inefficient. I think it could take hours to run.

If you wish to test it, try for example only the primes up to 100:

```
10 2?,{:x,{)x\%!},,2=},`
```

Comment: You can save a character by replacing `\;` with `*`. (You can also get much faster for the current character count by finding the first divisor rather than all of them: `10 6?,2>{.),2>{1$\%!}?=},\``

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, using multiplication there is a very neat trick.

Comment: There's one more char saving with a variable: replace `.,` with `:x,` and `\.@` with `x\ ` (whitespace is because of escaping issues with MD in comments) and remove `*`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor good one, thanks! I've edited my code.

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript, 25 (24) bytes

```
!10 6?,2>{.(@*.)@%!},n*\;
```

If the output format specified in the edited question is disregarded, one byte can be saved:

```
!10 6?,2>{.(@*.)@%!},`\;
```

This will print the primes as an array (like many other solutions do) rather than one per line.

#### How it works

The general idea is to use [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem), which states that *n* > 1 is prime if and only if

[image: (n - 1)! = -1 (mod n)]

```
!     # Push the logical NOT of the empty string (1). This is an accumulator.
10 6? # Push 10**6 = 1,000,000.
,2>   # Push [ 2 3 4 … 999,999 ].
{     # For each “N” in this array:
  .(  # Push “N - 1”.
  @   # Rotate the accumulator on top of the stack.
  *   # Multiply it with “N - 1”. The accumulator now hold “(N - 1)!”.
  .)  # Push “(N - 1)! + 1”
  @   # Rotate “N” on top of the stack.
  %!  # Push the logical NOT of “((N - 1)! + 1) % N”.
},    # Collect all “N” for which “((N - 1)! + 1) % N == 0” in an array.
n*    # Join that array by LF.
\;    # Discard the accumulator.
```

#### Benchmarks

Faster than trial division, but slower than the sieve of Eratosthenes. See [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27066/).

Answer (score 4):

## CJam - 11

```
1e6,{mp},N*
```

`1e6,` - array of 0 ... 999999
`{mp},` - select primes
`N*` - join with newlines

Comment: Isn't CJam more recent than this question?

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh, yes it is

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 110 bytes

```
void x(){for(int i=1;i++<1e6;)System.out.print(new String(new char[i]).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+")?"":(i+"\n"));}
```

Using unary division through regex as a primality test.

Comment: Nice approach. Never seen that prime-regex before. +1 from me. Although, [using a nested for-loop for prime-checking is slightly shorter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96177/52210). :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.x](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
2:1e6 .|>i->0∉i.%(2:i-1)==println(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/38jKMNVMQa/GLlPXzuBRR2emnqqGkVWmrqGmrW1BUWZeSU6eRqbm//8A)

Since the [other Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27021/48931) was posted, `primes` is no longer in the standard library. We use a couple of features:

- `∉` costs 3 bytes but is shorter than `in(...)`.
- We use the map syntax `f.x` over `map(f,x)`.
- We can broadcast `%` using `.%`.
- Floating point can exactly represent everything up to `1e6`, no problems there.
- We use a `==` short circuiting trick.

Answer (score 3):

## F#, <strike>100</strike> 94 bytes

```
let p n=
    let rec c i=i>n/2||(n%i<>0&&c(i+1))
    c 2
for n in 1..1000000 do if p n then printfn "%i" n
```

```
let p n={2..n-1}|>Seq.forall(fun x->n%x<>0)
{2..1000000}|>Seq.filter p|>Seq.iter(printfn "%i")
```

Answer (score 3):

## QBASIC, 75 bytes

```
FOR I=2 TO 1e6
    FOR J=2 TO I^.5
        IF I MOD J=0 THEN:GOTO X
    NEXT
    ?I
X:NEXT
```

I could have saved a character by going with FOR J = 2 TO I/2 but the run time was seriously slow. Runs at a much saner speed by only going to Sqrt I.

Answer (score 3):

### R, <s>45</s> 43 characters

```
for(i in 2:1e6)if(sum(!i%%2:i)<2)cat(i," ")
```

For each number x from 2 to 1e6, simply output it if the number of x mod 2 to x that are equal to 0 is less than 2.

Comment: The first number produced by this code is 1, but 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 25

Assuming you don't know the number of primes less than 10^6:

```
Prime@Range@PrimePi[10^6]
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, 16 chars

```
1]\(#~1&p:)i.1e6
```

Without the output format requirement, this can be reduced to **13** chars:

```
(#~1&p:)i.1e6
```

`1]\` just takes the rank 1 array of primes, turns it into a rank 2 array, and puts each prime on its own row -- and so the interpreter's default output format turns the one line list into one prime per line.

`(#~ f) y` is basically `filter`, where `f` returns a boolean for each element in `y`. `i.1e6` is the range of integers [0,1000000), and `1&p:` is a boolean function that returns 1 for primes.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (433643)

My (not so clever) attempt was to use factor to factor the product.

```
factor ${PRODUCT}
```

Unfortunately with large numbers the product is of course huge.  It also took over 12 hours to run.  I decided to post it though because I thought it was unique.

[Here is the full code.](http://pastebin.com/TYQLBZ5d)

If it was primes under six it would be reasonable.

```
  factor 30
```

Oh well, I tried.

Comment: +1 This answer is truly diabolical. Not quite precomputed result (it saves quite a bit of characters), and much much more terrible to compute :) It's quite possibly also an example that makes the optimized `factor` perform much worse than the basic trial division algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

### NARS2000 APL - 9 characters

```
¯2π⍳2π1e6
```

Quite a boring answer.

Short explanation:

```
¯2 π  ⍝ generate the Nth prime for N
⍳     ⍝ in the range 1 to
2 π   ⍝ the number of primes less than or equal to
1e6   ⍝ a million
```

Comment: This is sinister black magic.

Comment: @professorfish I assume I should add an explanation?

Comment: yessssssss (putting in extra sssss because of char limit_)

Comment: You need `⍪` for the proper output (and btw, `¯2π⍳78498` is much simpler).

Answer (score 3):

## Commodore 64 Basic, 55 characters

```
1F┌I=2TO10^6:F┌J=2TOI/2:IF(I/J=INT(I/I))G┌3
2N─:?I
3N─I
```

PETSCII substitutions: `┌` = `SHIFT+O`, `─` = `SHIFT+E`

Incredibly slow: first, because the algorithm is extremely inefficient (it tries dividing by every value less than half the candidate number), second, because the Commodore 64 is slow, and third, because Commodore Basic does all its math in emulated floating-point on an 8-bit CPU.

### Theoretical solution, 82 characters

```
1M=10^6:D╮S(M):F┌I=2TO1000:F┌J=I^2TOMST─I:S(J)=-1:N─:N─:F┌I=2TOM:IF(N┌S(I))T|:?I
2N─
```

`╮` = `SHIFT+I`, `┌` = `SHIFT+O`, `─` = `SHIFT+E`, `|` = `SHIFT+H`

If this program could run on an actual Commodore 64, it would be much faster than the above.  However, it can't: the sieve alone would take 5,000,007 bytes out of the 38,911 bytes a C64 has available for Basic programs.  Note the use of `-1` instead of `1` when denoting composite values in the array: C64 Basic doesn't have a true boolean negation; `NOT` performs a two's complement instead.

Comment: I think that should be `INT(I/J)` not `I/I`. Btw. that´s 56 bytes; and 56 characters (the last line needs a RETURN as well so it gets recognized). `1F┌I=2TO10^6:F┌J=2TOI/2:IF(I/J!=INT(I/I))N─:?I` and `2N─I` is four characters shorter and six bytes smaller. Nice approach though.

Comment: Oh and for those that think that integer varibales would be faster: They´re not. Commodore Basic transforms integer values to float for calculations.

Answer (score 3):

## HPPPL, <s>90</s> 89 chars

(HP Prime Programming Language), for the HP Prime color graphing calculator.

```
export p()begin local i;for i from 2 to 1e6 do if isprime(i)=1 then print(i) end;end;end;
```

Output to the terminal is quite slow on the Prime, so the program takes quite a while to run. Printing out all primes using the emulator takes about 88 seconds on my i5 2410M laptop.

As my google account is messed up, I have to start all over again with a new account... so be it. My photo and name are the same as before ;)

You can try out the program with the free HP Prime emulator available here:

http://www.hp-prime.de/en/category/13-emulator

Answer (score 3):

## APL (Dyalog), 15 chars

```
⍪(⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳1E6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9oCgzN7U4NC8ltcjQ1fj/o95VGo@6FtU96pihd3j6o94VmoaP2iY/6t0Mluxo/4@qHgA) (only goes until one thousand as TIO does not allot enough memory for a million)

`⍳1E6` first million **ɩ**ntegers

`1↓` drop one

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`⊢` the argument (all the numbers 2…1000000)

`~` except those that are in

`∘.×⍨` the multiplication table (using the argument as both vertical and horizontal axis)

`⍪` table (makes list into column)

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 34 bytes

`6@=9<CR>o<Tab>0<Esc>V{g<C-A>dj=:g/\v^(<Tab><Tab>+)\1+</d<CR>`

This is a direct adaptation of my top solution to [Prime Numbers](https://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/4d1c27940e3d7832db000010). The difference is... here I have to go up to a million. This forces a cool tactic to put `999999` into the readahead, but it also makes this solution impossible to run. You won't even get past the setup making the number array, because you'd need to fill more than half a terabyte of RAM (without overhead). And if you ever got to the regex algorithm... well, it sucks. You'd never finish.

This solution requires `:set autoindent noexpandtab`, which you might have set already, might not. It also requires computer hardware that doesn't exist.

- `6@=9<CR>`: Cool trick to write `999999` in 5 bytes. Integer 9 gets evaluated into the expression register as text. That "macro" is run 6 times.
- `o<Tab>0<Esc>`: Make N (999,999) lines of zeroes, with stair-step indent. This is kind of like what happens when you paste in insert mode without doing `:set paste`.
- `V{g<C-A>`: Visual increment to turn the `0`s into a list of numbers 1-999,999. Conveniently leaves cursor on top.
- `dj`: Remove the blank (zero) and 1 lines.
- `=:`: Vim users rarely think of the `:` command as an operator, but it is one (a charwise operator, surprisingly). Runs the `=` out to where the `:` command would move the cursor (top to bottom in this case).
- `\v^(<Tab><Tab>+)\1+<`: Regex that matches a composite number of tabs. If you haven't, watch the [VimCast episode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/vimgolf-prime-numbers/), which covers an old version of this solution. The `:g//d` will delete those lines. The cursor will end on the last remaining line, which will act as the operator for `=` to remove all indent.

## Vim, 36 bytes (actually runs)

- `6@=9<CR>O0<Esc>V{g<C-A>:%norm~V$EkdYo@0D@.<C-O>@.<CR>d`

This `:normal` macro is a proper sieve of Eratosthenes that cleans up after itself. I actually ran this out to 1,000,000. Took 10-15 minutes. The algorithm is quite good, but the data structure (array of lines in Vim) comes with a big toll. I [wrote about it](http://udioica.blogspot.com/2013/11/prime-numbers.html) in more detail a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>55 53</s> 51 bytes

```php
for($n=1;1e6>$i=$n++;$i||print"$n
")while($n%$i--);
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee8caaecff0f09fda0823815e52fa5a5a72d913a). (TiO only runs to 10K; 1M would exceed the time limit.)

The outer loop runs `$n` from 1 to 1 million.
The inner loop is the primality test: loops `$i` down from `$n-1` until `$i` is a divisor of `$n`.
If that divisor is 1, `$n` is a prime and will be printed in the post-condition of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [FORTRAN 90](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/), 80 bytes

```
DO I=2,1E2;D=1;DO J=2,I**.5;IF(MOD(I,J)==0)D=0;ENDDO;IF(D==1)PRINT*,I;ENDDO;END
```

This is the same as below, but in a newer and less rigorous version.

---

## [FORTRAN 77](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/index.html), <s>104</s> 95 bytes

```
      DOI=2,1E6;D=1;DOJ=2,I**.5;IF(MOD(I,J).EQ.0)D=0;
      ENDDO;IF(D.EQ.1)PRINT*,I;ENDDO;END
```

Works with `gfortran`. Not sure if the `DO I=...` and `DO J=...` works without spaces in other compilers.

(Modification: program name supressed; I just learned that it's optional!)

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 75

```
print filter(lambda n:n==2 or all(n%i for i in range(2,n)),range(15485864))
```

Not terribly efficient though, it actually gives me a out of memory error in Jython.

Here's a (slightly) more efficient version:

```
import math
print [2]+filter(lambda n:all(n%i for i in xrange(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2)),xrange(3,15485864,2))
```

This version took approximately 8 minutes to run.

Comment: quite a big variety of speeds here, one of my answers took 4.5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, 58

```
2 to 1000000 map{x=>if(2 to x/2 forall(x%_!=0))println(x)}
```

or

```
2 to 1000000 filter{x=>2 to x/2 forall(x%_!=0)}map println
```

Comment: Giving last prime number can save one character.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 65 chars

```
main=print[x|x<-[2..999999::Int],null[i|i<-[2..x-1],mod x i==0]]
```

Comment: Nice.  Could you save a few by removing the ::Int ?

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>12</s>, 11

```
primes(1e6)
```

Write 1000000 as 1e6

Comment: 1e6 is even shorter ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-98, 119 characters

Because if it can be done, it can be done in Befunge! Probably not optimal. Works in 98 but not 93 because of the difference in how many bits a cell can store.

```
2.300p210pv>a,00g:.2+00>p"d"::**v
>00g1-10g`!|Prime Get> ^|p012!`\<
| %g01g00 <>10g1+10pv  v<
>00g:2+00#^        #<^#<@
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 70

```
Enumerable.Range(1,1e6).Where(n=>Enumerable.Range(2,n).All(x=>x%n!=0))
```

You're not going to see much here though for a LONG time...

Comment: There are several reasons why this is wrong. (1) You cannot implicitly convert from a `double` `1e6` to an `int`, but `int` is required by `Range`. (2) The inner `Range` must take at most `n-2` terms, otherwise you will test `n % n` which is clearly `0`. (3) You write `x%n` when you want `n%x`. Fixing these issues, something like this will work: `Enumerable.Range(2,999999).Where(n=>Enumerable.Range(2,n-2).All(x=>n%x!=0))` However, this still does not output the numbers; the requirement was one per line.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP - 72 bytes

```
<?for($i=1;$i++^999999;print$d?~ı.$i:'')for($d=$j=2;$j<$i&&$d=$i%$j++;);
```

Hexdump:

```
0000000 3c 3f 66 6f 72 28 24 69 3d 31 3b 24 69 2b 2b 5e
0000010 39 39 39 39 39 39 3b 70 72 69 6e 74 24 64 3f 7e
0000020 f5 2e 24 69 3a 27 27 29 66 6f 72 28 24 64 3d 24
0000030 6a 3d 32 3b 24 6a 3c 24 69 26 26 24 64 3d 24 69
0000040 25 24 6a 2b 2b 3b 29 3b                        
0000048
```

Kinda slow, could be optimised (for 6 bytes) by division-checking until the square root of each number only, like so:

```
<?for($i=1;$i++^999999;print$d?~ı.$i:'')for($d=$j=2;$j<sqrt($i)&&$d=$i%$j++;);
```

Answer (score 2):

### PARI/GP, 26 bytes

Simple solution:

```
forprime(p=2,1e6,print(p))
```

Less-efficient solutions, one per line:

```
prodeuler(p=2,1e6,print(p));
apply(n->print(n),primes(78498));
apply(n->print(n),primes([2,1e6]));
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript es6 66 bytes

I was surprised to not see JS in here so I thought I'd put in a word for her

```
//takes about 19 minutes to run on my work pc
for(i=2,l=[];i<1e6;++i)l.every(a=>i/a%1)&&l.push(console.log(i)|i)
```

Comment: You can save a byte by incrementing in the compare `for(i=1,l=[];++i<1e6;)`

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
1e6Zq
```

Explanation:

```
1e6   % push 10000 to stack
   Zq % primes up to top-of-stack number
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

*saved one byte thanks to Martin Ender*

```
()=>{for(i=0;i<1e6;i++)!/^.?$|^(..+)\1+$/.test('1'.repeat(i))&&alert(i);}
```

Tests all numbers under 1 million against a regex. [Regex Explanation](https://iluxonchik.github.io/regular-expression-check-if-number-is-prime/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
10*6ÆRY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QQMvscFtQ5P//AA)

```
10*6    # One million in scientific notation (10^6 = 1,000,000).
    ÆR  # List of primes less than one million.
      Y # Join the list with newlines.
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I improved the formatting and added in a Try It Online link. Also [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdrPDbUGR//8DAA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing not sure if it was in the syntax at the time, but you could replace `10*6` with `ȷ6` to save a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2; 67 Bytes

```
n,p=3,[2]
while n<1e5:exec'print n;p+=[n]'*all(n%x for x in p);n+=2
```

Checks current number against all previous primes, and if not divisible by any of them, prints number and adds to list

The advantage of the while loop compared to other methods is that python will allow direct comparison against a number of the form "1e5", rather than having to use a long form or convert it to an int

Still takes a long time to run

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
6°ÅPε,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7NCGw60B57bq/P8PAA)

Explanation:

```
6°ÅPε,
6°       Push 1000000 to stack (10^6)
  ÅP     List of all primes < 1000000
    ε,   Print each element of the list
```

Comment: You can save a byte changing `ε,` to `»` (join by newlines; after which the result is implicitly output).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 27 bytes

```perl6
grep(&is-prime,^)>>.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@9KLVAQy2zWLegKDM3VSfuw7S18zTt7PSKEyv//wcA)

Filters all the primes from 0 to a million minus 1 and then prints.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
L³õ fj
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=TLP1IGZq)

```
L³õ fj
L          :100
 ³         :Cubed
  õ        :Range [1,L³]
    f      :Filter
     j     :  Prime
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
k4'æ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrNCfDpiIsIiIsIiJd)

```
k4   # 1m
  '  # 1...^ filtered by
   æ # is prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```
Z6gN
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FkuizNL9IEyoyAIoDQA)

Note: this is *very* slow (it times out on ATO), so here's a version which prints the primes up to 1000: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FkuijNP9IEyoyAIoDQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Z6    # Push 10**6 (1000000)
  g   # Filter (range of ^) for:
   N  #  Primes
      # N flag joins by newlines
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (111)

```
x=1000000,s[1000000],j;main(i){while(++i<x)for(j=2*i;j<x;j+=i)
s[j]=1;for(i=1;++i<x;)if(!s[i])printf("%d\n",i);}
```

## C (112)

```
x=1000000,s[1000000],j;main(i){while(++i<x)for(j=2*i;j<x;j+=i)
s[j]=1;i=1;while(++i<x)if(!s[i])printf("%d\n",i);}
```

## C (113, over 25% faster)

```
x=1000,s[1000000],j;main(i){while(++i<x)for(j=i*i;j<x*x;j+=i)
s[j]=1;i=1;while(++i<x*x)if(!s[i])printf("%d\n",i);}
```

## C (ungolfed)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sieve[1000000];
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
        for (j = i * i; j < 1000000; j += i)
            sieve[j] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
        if (!sieve[i])
            printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i=1;while(++i<E)` can be improved to `for(i=1;++i<E;)`. `for(j=2*i;j<x;j+=i)s[j]=1;` can be improved to `for(j=1;++j<x;)s[j*i]=1;`

Comment: Thanks. For your second improvement, though, considering that `j` would no longer be a direct index to the sieve, wouldn't comparing against `x` cause the program to significantly overrun the array?

Comment: Fair point. One big improvement still possible, though: use a single loop. Can't think how I missed it earlier.

Comment: As in, using one loop in total, or replacing the first pair of loops with one loop, resulting in two loops? I don't think the former is possible, as it'd mean printing while the sieve is in an incomplete state.

Comment: Sure it's possible. The part of the sieve up to `i` is complete.

Comment: If you moved the declaration of `s` inside the loop you could use `x` instead of `1000000`, I think you could save a character or two even taking the additional `int` and `;` into account.

Comment: Can't you do `x=1000000,s[x]`? I'm not an expert in C though.

Comment: Also, instead of `s[j]=1;for(i=1...`, do `s[j]=i=1;for(...`

Comment: You can probably just use `1e6` rather than `1000000` in most contexts. It's a floating-point number rather than an integer, but it tends to get implicitly converted.

Answer (score 1):

## C - 67

```
$ cat x.c
main(p,t){for(p=1;t=2,++p<1e6;t<p||printf("%d\n",p))while(p%t++);}
$ wc -c x.c 
67 x.c
$ gcc -O3 x.c -o x
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
$ ./x | wc -l
78498
```

It's sloooooow... don't ask... :-D

I got an even shorter variant (54 bytes) but unluckily it prints the biggest prime first. ;-(

Maybe it fits in a different code golf... someday... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure - 95 bytes

This is a simple, unoptimised function which prints the primes.

```
(defn p[](doseq[i(range 2 1e6):when(every? false?(map #(=(mod i %)0)(range 2 i)))](println i)))
```

Now, I wanted to create something nice too, so here is a function that creates a lazy infinite list of primes.

```clojure
(defn primes
  ([]
    (concat [2 3] (primes 5)))
  ([n]
    (lazy-seq
      (first
        (for [i     (range)
              :let  [i (+ i n)]
              :when (every? false? (map #(= (mod i %) 0)
                                        (range 2 (Math/sqrt i))))]
          (cons i (primes (+ i 2))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab (12)

Pretty simple=)

```
primes(1e6)'
```

Comment: So simple that there is already http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6274/21348

Comment: Oh, didn't see that one, but I have to say that mine is way shorter=)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 183 characters

```
import java.util.stream.*;
class P{public static void main(String[]a){
IntStream.range(1,1000000).filter(i->!IntStream.range(2,i).anyMatch(j->i%j==0)).forEach(System.out::println);
}}
```

Performance is not optimal, but code is well readable. For faster computation could be code extended to use parallel streams:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
class P{public static void main(String[]a){
IntStream.range(1,1000000).parallel().filter(i->!IntStream.range(2,i).anyMatch(j->i%j==0)).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}}
```

Comment: I think you can remove some of the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

**Java - 101 characters**

Ungolfed version:

```
for(int i=3, j; i < 1000000; i++) {
    for(j = 2; j < i / 2; j++)
        if (i % j ==0)
            break;
    System.out.printf(i % j != 0 ? i + "%n" : "");
}
```

Golfed version:

```
for(int i=3,j;i<1000000;i++){for(j=2;j<i/2;j++)if(i%j==0)break;System.out.printf(i%j!=0?i+"%n":"");}
```

Comment: @Martin Büttner Oups. Fixed it.

Comment: IDK, if that is an accepted format in Codegolf, you have to wrap it into a function, a lambda or a program. It helps other people to test your code faster and gives everyone using the same language a fair playing ground.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl6 - 47

```
for 1..10**6 {(1 x$_)~~/^(11+?)$0+$/ or say $_}
```

credit to [Gowtham's perl solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/13098/30149)

- `1000000` better written as `10**6`
- `print "$_\n"` became `say $_`
- `=~` became `~~`
- needed to add whitespace in front of the `x` operator

Comment: you can use superscript version of 10**6 > 10⁶
so you can shorten range from 1..10**6 to ^10⁶
+ you can move the for on the right side and it becomes 41 chars

`(1 x$_)~~/^(11+?)$0+$/ or say $_ for ^10⁶`

Comment: You could also use `.say` instead of `say $_`.

Answer (score 1):

### Dart - 75 chars

Loop based version:

```
main(i,j){for(i=2;i<1e6;i++)l:{for(j=2;j<i;j++)if(i%j<1)break l;print(i);}}
```

It's *much* faster if you change `j<i` to `j*j<=i`, but not shorter!

Alternative List based version (107 chars)
Not going to win any records without a shorter way to generate the list.

```
main(p,q){p=new List.generate(999998,(x)=>x+2);while(!p.isEmpty){print(q=p[0]);p.removeWhere((x)=>x%q<1);}}
```

Ungolfed

```
    main(p,q) { 
      p = new List.generate(999998, (x) => x + 2);
      while (!p.isEmpty) { 
        print(q = p[0]);
        p.removeWhere((x) => x%q < 1);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Bacchus](https://sites.google.com/site/bacchuslanguage/), 34 bytes

```
\n[2..1E6]a(Öp:a(·=1.Öw)?),·¨
```

Explanation:

```
\n            Prepare the output to be one in each line

[2..1E6]      Generates an array from 2 to 1000000

:a            Push the array to the stack

(),·¨         For each element on the array we previously pushed to the stack

Öp:a          If current element of the for-each loop is Prime push 1 to the stack. Otherwise, push 0.

(·=1.Öw)?     If last pushed element is 1 then print current element of the for each loop.
```

Most of the code is used to output each prime in different lines. Otherwise a much shorter code (10 bytes) would be

```
[2..1E6]p#
```

Answer (score 1):

### LiveScript - 71 bytes

I was goofing around, trying to golf Sieve of Eratosthenes. I'm quite happy with the result. It uses prelude.ls.

```
x=1e6;[2 to x]|>unfoldr ([x]:l)->|l>[]=>[console.log<|x,l|>filter (%x)]
```

It outputs to the console. You can try the code in http://livescript.net - I recommend using lower limit than 1e6, because it gets slow at those numbers and probably hangs your browser for a while. I couldn't find a way to stop LS from inlining `[2 to 1e6]`, so I had to creae a var for it.

Just for the sake of it, the original function I mangled the first one from:

```
p=->[2 to it]|>unfoldr ([x]:l)->|l>[]=>[x,l|>filter (%x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### JS, <s>100</s> <s>67</s> 57

By xem and subzey

Execute this in the browser's console or nodeJS.

Short version: 57b. (it's very long to end: ~ 20 min)

```
for(i=1;1e6>++i;p&&console.log(i))for(p=j=i;j-->2;)p*=i%j
```

Faster version, 100b (ends in ~ 1 min)

```
p=[];for(i=2;1E6>i;i++)for(t=0,j=i;1E6>j;j+=i)t&&(p[j]=1),t=1;for(i=2;1E6>i;i++)p[i]||console.log(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog - 129

Not a very short variant, but reasonably fast. A simple implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
:-initialization m.
F+S+X:-G is F,(G=<1e6,X=G;G<1e6,(G+S)+S+X).
m:-assert(i-1),2+1+I,\+i-I,write(I),nl,I*I+I+J,assert(i-J),1=0;!.
```

Invocation:

```
time swipl -qf ./prime.pl < /dev/null | wc -l

78498

real    0m3.646s
user    0m3.468s
sys     0m0.264s
```

Readable:

```
:- initialization(main).

between2(From, _, X) :-
    X is From,
    X =< 1000000.
between2(From, StepSize, X) :-
    Y is From,
    Y < 1000000,
    between2(Y + StepSize, StepSize, X).

main :-
    assert(stroke(1)), % shorter than ":-dynamic stroke/1."
    between2(2, 1, I),
    \+ stroke(I),
    write(I), nl,
    between2(I*I, I, J),
    assert(stroke(J)),
    fail.
main.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 75

```
map{my($a,$b)=($_,0);for(2..$a-1){$a%$_==0&&$b++}$b||print"$a\n"}(2..10**6)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) - <strike>14</strike> 12 chars

<strike>`Fkr2^T6IqlPk1k`</strike>

Thanks so much to @FryAmTheEggman for removing two chars from filter and ![1:] instead of ==1. As you probably can guess I learned Pyth literally yesterday. :)

```
jbf!tPTtU^T6
```

Omg I actually beat Mathematica builtins. Its very simple it just loops through 2 to a million and uses trick that prime numbers have one number in thier prime factorization which pyth happens to have a function for.

```
jb:    Join with \n as sperator
f:     filter by
!tPT:  not tail of prime factorization of loop variable(tail would be falsey if len 1 so then negate)
tU^T6:  filter through range 2-million
```

It does take a verrrrrry long time to run, but if you want to just see it run, you can change the 6 to a 2 for primes under hundred.

Comment: Using pyth's `filter` function is a tad shorter: `jbf!tPTtU^T6`. This also saves a char by checking `len(prime_factors(n)[1:])>0`, which could also be added to your code: `I!tPk`. (This works because an empty list is False, and a list of any other length is True) Good luck with Pyth ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jagl](http://github.com/globby/jagl) Alpha 1.2 - 14 bytes

**Not competing, language is younger than question**

```
1e6r{m}%{PZp}/
```

Prints on separate lines.

Comment: Is this language younger than the question?

Comment: Yes, I am not competing. Clarified in the answer @githubphagocyte

Comment: @githubphagocyte :)

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby <del>37</del> 32**

```
(2..1e6).map{|x|p x if x.prime?}
```

Comment: yeah that makes so much sense. THanks :)

Comment: Actually, I can't find any documentation of `prime?`. Have you tested this?

Comment: yeah it works great. Here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Integer.html#method-i-prime-3F

Comment: This only works if the Prime module is loaded. You need to `require 'prime'` otherwise you get `NoMethodError: undefined method \`prime?' for 2:Fixnum`

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL, 141

Assuming a resultset is valid output, here's code that works with SQL Server 2008 R2.  It uses a table to store previously found primes.  The table is initialized with 2, and all odd integers greater than that are checked against the contents of the table at the point in time of the check.  Runtime and efficiency obviously were not concerns....

```
DECLARE @ INT=3SELECT 2 p INTO # l:IF NULL=ALL(SELECT 1FROM # WHERE @%p=0)INSERT # VALUES(@)SET @+=2IF @<1e6GOTO l SELECT p FROM # ORDER BY p
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 28 bytes

```py
for i in primes(1e6):print i
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy9SyFTIzFMoKMrMTS3WMEw107QCsvNKFDIBitEJhQ==&lang=sage)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It's Python 2

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
V^T6IP_NN
```

Explanation:

```
V starts a for loop from 0 to the next number, keeping N as the value
T = 10 and so ^T6 = 10^6 = 1000000
I is if, P_N checks if N is prime and returns True or False based on the result.
The final N is just to print it.
```

I'm new to Pyth so it's likely not the best solution. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>100</s> <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```java
o->{for(int i=1,n,j;i++<1e6;){for(n=i,j=2;j<n;n=n%j++<1?0:n);if(n>1)System.out.print(n);}}
```

-3 bytes by thanks to *@Nevay*.
-5 bytes by converting Java 7 to Java 8.

I know there are already a few other Java answers. I didn't knew which to choose to put the comment on with my golfed method, so I decided to post this separate answer. Not to mention it's slightly or a lot shorter than any of the other current Java answers so far.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY49DsIwDEZ3TuEFKVF/RBkYSAMnAAZGxBBCihJSp2pSJIR69pAWFkv2s/09I16icJ1Cc39GaYX3cBAaPwsAjUH1jZAKjlML8HL6DpKcbkbJAI6yNB0XqfgggpZwBAQeXbH7NK4n6Rw0r3LMDdNZVldqw@hMkOvc8DUzNTLkuDQT3a@2SJluCO4qen77oNrSDaHs@vTIIklwHCOb4rrhZlPcP3W2apMzOYe0@7hcQdCfMJaS4GDt33SMXw)

```java
o->{                          // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=1,n,j;            //  Initialize some integers
      i++<1e6;){              //  Loop (1) from 2 through 1,000,000 (exclusive)
    for(n=i,j=2;              //   Set some integers
        j<n;                  //   Inner loop (2) from 2 through `n` (exclusive)
      n=                      //    Change `n` to:
        n%j++<1?              //     If `n` is divisible by `j`:
         0                    //      Change `n` to 0 (which means it isn't a prime)
        :                     //     Else:
         n                    //      Leave `n` unchanged
    );                        //   End of inner loop (2)
    if(n>1)                   //   If `n` is larger than 1, which means it's a prime:
      System.out.println(n);  //    Print `n` + new-line
  }                           //  End of loop (1)
}                             // End of method
```

Comment: You can use `if(n>1)System.out.println(n);` instead of `System.out.print(n>1?n+"\n":"");` to save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 104 bytes

```
set i 2
time {set p 1;set j 2;while \$j<$i {if $i%$j==0 {set p 0};incr j};if $p {puts $i};incr i} 999998
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYoxDoAgFEN3T9HhuyOTBrmJG8H4CRoiGAfi2RES7fLS9iXjS4k2gSG7xLtFbi1gUI0OUt0be4uF3EyMzCuIe3Jai18Vj@LDnHCV9Q3I4Uqxat/OD6aWsZQX)

Unfortunately I could not find an online Tcl interpreter which does not time out running it.

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 110 bytes

```
set i 2
time {set p 1;set j 2;while \$j<$i {if $i%$j==0 {set p 0;break};incr j};if $p {puts $i};incr i} 999998
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7DoAgFAR7T7EF9milQW9io@QZH35CFGNBODtCottMdjJObzFe5MCoC8c7wednUalMg1o9C2@EQZhOMDzPEFwK0/fyT6WaThrXoPjQJ0xiaiy8vd2V4s9zQJvXxPgC)

## tcl, 115

```
set i 2
time {set p 1;set j 2;while \$j<$i {if ![expr $i%$j] {set p 0;break};incr j};if $p {puts $i};incr i} 999998
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSTB0eUJDTk9uVlk)

---

## tcl, 201

My still not golfed answer:

```
for {set i 2} {$i<$1000000} {incr i} {
    set p 1
    for {set j 2} {$j<$i} {incr j} {
        if {[expr $i%$j] == 0} {
            set p 0
            break
        }
    }

    if $p {puts $i}
}
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSU4tLS1tdjhZbTg)

Comment: [102](https://tio.run/##LcoxCoAwEETR3lOMsPZr2pib2EnEDVGCRiyCZ1@jWD0@M3mKqofPEJgmy@pR3kpg@xpg7LVI9BgpDCQoMoOko@Ac19imHem2n6E6o6WEks581Ns/yI2emVUf)

Comment: [100](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoAgFAX3neIFtte2dpR2ovTF4pNGC/Hs9qlWw8BMcal3OtwJGgrtHvUTm30BQ7@MmO29UfJYVVwUSRSgaBIx/8DNvozCgFExKl8lS9UajNa69wc)

Comment: [94](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/My@5SCGTqyQzN1WhGsKxLk4tUchSMLQuz8jMSVWIUcmyUckESqYpqGSqRoPVZMXaGCokFaUmZtdaA8WBSmxtQWoKSkuKgapqaxUsweD/fwA) - note my previous bytecounts should be 2 longer since i lowered loop limit

Comment: [88](https://tio.run/##JYo7DoAgEAV7T/EK7KFGTmIslKxxEY0BjIXh7IhazidZXwrvNoCbxBvh/kFHSnBQ@lrYE1T1MwS3/Zfd0ClMgcY169c7YwTjPs4U65QzlJSylAc)

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP, <s>100</s> 95 bytes

It works by iterating 1,000,000 times and then using this regular expression on a unary number to check if it's prime. It's not the smallest PHP solution submitted, but thought I'd submit it just so it's here.

```
for($i=0;$i<=1e6;$i++)if(preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/',str_repeat("1",$i))==0)echo$i.PHP_EOL;
```

Matchu explains how the regular expression works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296068/3000179

First 50: https://eval.in/746404

Comment: Can you remove the space between `for($i=0;$i<=1e6;$i++)` and everything else?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline yep, thanks!

Comment: Great algorithm! 28 bytes shorter: `while(++$i<1e6)preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/',$s.=1)||print"$i\n";` (not tested). Save one more byte with a literal newline. Have you tried `ereg` instead of `preg_match`? That would save another 8 bytes, shrinking your solution to 58 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes (CP437)

Non-competitive, obviously, but I don't think anyone will mind since this question is almost 5 years old ;)

```
6°P
```

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Since there is not yet an answer in 05AB1E.

```
T6mGNp–
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xCzX3a/gUcPk//8B)

Comment: Why is the input for this 22?

Comment: @carusocomputing There is no reason for that... removed it

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

`V^T6IqlPN1N`

## Explanation

`V^T6` - For loop using looping variable N in range 0 to 10 ^ 6

`IqlPN1` - If len(prime_factors(n)) == 1

`N` - implicity print n (if it is prime)

Try running the code here: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%5ET6IqlPN1N&debug=0

Note that this seems to take too long to run on the online interpreter, so  try replacing `V^T6` with `V^T3`, which will run (and clearly if it can print primes up to 1,000, it will work with 1,000,000)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 9 bytes

```
78497ǰƖřᵽ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f3MLE0uL4hmPTjs58uHXv//8A)

```
78498ǰƖřᵽ
78497      - push 7, 8, 4, 9, and 7 on the stack
    ǰ      - join everything on stack w/no delimiters
     Ɩ     - casts to int
      ř    - construct range from 78498 to 1 ([1,2,3,..., 78497, 78498])
       ᵽ   - push xth prime for every item in list
```

Doesn't meet the timeout rq on tio, but it would work, you can try it with lower numbers the reason for 78498 is that that is the 0 indexed prime under a million

Comment: You can save a byte (or two) and get it to not time out on tio: 6ᴇřĐṗ*žÁ. The Á is only to make the output match the format specified in the question, and can be removed if the output can be an array.

Comment: I feel like that's different enough to post as your own answer, but [if you don't want to](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/ethics-around-improving-answers-in-comments), I'll update.

Comment: I'll post it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) 65 bytes

```
j;f(i){for(;++i<1e6;)for(j=2;!printf("%d\n"+(i>j)*3,i)&&i%j++;);}
```

[Try it online! ( stops at 1000 )](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOk0jU7M6Lb9Iw1pbO9PGMNXYWhPEy7I1slYsKMrMK0nTUFJNiclT0tbItMvS1DLWydRUU8tUzdLWtta0rv2fm5iZpwE0QQPEAQA)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOk0jU7M6Lb9IwzrLVls708Yw1dhaE8zX1s7Sz7RXLCjKzCtJ01BSTYnJU9LJ1LTKVM2y1rSu/Z@bmJmnAdSrAeIAAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
6ᴇřĐṗ*žÁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9weXT//zbhtIfFmcSQ4bmXKsW@w4H//w)

Explanation:

```
6ᴇ            Push 1000000
ř             Push [1,2,...,999999,1000000]
Đ             Duplicate top of stack
ṗ             Is each element prime (pushes array of booleans)
*             Multiply top two on stack element-wise
ž             Remove all zeros
Á             Push contents of array onto stack
              Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 128 bytes

```
X's1
while X-999999
let X be+1
let D be X
P's1
while P and D-2
let D be-1
let M be X/D
turn up M
let P be X/D aint M

if P say X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in) - *Extremely* inefficient; knock a few `9`s off the second line to have it complete in a sane amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes`, 22 bytes

```
1e6 primes-upto stack.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVdQlJmbWqxQUJRaUlIJ5OSVKFj/N0w1U4BI6JYWlOQrFJckJmfr/f8PAA)

- `1e6 primes-upto` Get a list of primes up to a million
- `stack.` Prettyprint each element of a sequence, one per line

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```c
i;main(n){for(;n<1e6;i||printf("%d ",n))for(i=n++;n%i--;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM08jT7M6Lb9IwzrPxjDV2DqzpqagKDOvJE1DSTVFQUknT1MTJJtpm6etbZ2nmqmra61pXfv/PwA) (upto 1000)

Answer (score 1):

## [CellTail](https://github.com/mousetail/CellTail/blob/main/README.md), 165 bytes

```
I=-1;O=N;N,-1,N:N,(1,1,1),N;999999..,N,N:N,N,N;A,(a,a,b),N:N,a,a+1;A,(a,b,0),N:N,(a+1,2),N;A,(a,b),N:N,(a,b,a%b),N;A,(a,b,c),N:N,(a,b+1,a%(b+1)),N;a,N,N:N,(a,1,a),N;
```

Should *eventually* produce the correct output, will take a very long time though.

[Try it online](https://mousetail.github.io/CellTail/#ST0tMTtPPU47TiwtMSxOOk4sKDEsMSwxKSxOOzk5OTk5OS4uLCBOLE46TixOLE47QSwoYSxhLGIpLE46TixhLGErMTtBLChhLGIsMCksTjpOLChhKzEsMiksTjtBLChhLGIpLE46TiwoYSxiLGElYiksTjtBLChhLGIsYyksTjpOLChhLGIrMSxhJShiKzEpKSxOO2EsTixOOk4sKGEsMSxhKSxOOw==)

[Try it online, numbers up to 1000 so it will actually complete in a few minutes](https://mousetail.github.io/CellTail/#ST0tMTtPPU47TiwtMSxOOk4sKDEsMSwxKSxOOzk5OS4uLCBOLE46TixOLE47QSwoYSxhLGIpLE46TixhLGErMTtBLChhLGIsMCksTjpOLChhKzEsMiksTjtBLChhLGIpLE46TiwoYSxiLGElYiksTjtBLChhLGIsYyksTjpOLChhLGIrMSxhJShiKzEpKSxOO2EsTixOOk4sKGEsMSxhKSxOOw==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 34 bytes

```arturo
loop 1..1e6=>[if prime?<=&->print]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?jAygbd)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 68

```
print[a for a in range(2,999999)if all(a%b for b in range(2,a/2+1))]
```

Sadly, there's no hope in seeing it terminate within any reasonable time frame...

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 126 chars, Using Sieve of Eratosthenes

```
import Data.Set 
g i n m|i>n=[]|member i m=g(i+1)n m|1<2=i:g(i+1)n(fromList[i*i,i*i+i..n]`union`m)
main=print$g 2(10**6)empty
```

Run quite fast on my machine.

```
% ghc primeList1.hs -O
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( primeList1.hs, primeList1.o )
Linking primeList1 ...

% time ./primeList1 >/dev/null
./primeList1 > /dev/null  5.04s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 5.100 total
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 94 (optimized for speed, 2.655 secs)

```
(a=[*2..n=1e6]).each{|p|next if !p
break if p*p>n
(p*p).step(n,p){|m|a[m]=nil}}
puts a.compact
```

Ran in 2.655 seconds on my machine, which is pretty good considering how slow Ruby is.

Here's how I timed it:

```
t = Time.now

(a=[*2..n=1e6]).each{|p|next if !p
break if p*p>n
(p*p).step(n,p){|m|a[m]=nil}}
puts a.compact

puts Time.now - t
```

It takes a ridiculously long time to output to stdout, so I did `sieve.rb > sieve.txt` (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

## (M)AWK - <strike>104</strike> <strike>103</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>98</strike> <strike>97</strike> 87

```
BEGIN{for(n=2;n<1e6;){if(n in L)p=L[n]
else print p=n
for(N=p+n++;N in L;)N+=p
L[N]=p}}
```

---

Old:

The 'x' file:

```
BEGIN{for(n=2;n<1e6;){if(n in L){p=L[n]
del L[n]}else print p=n
for(N=p+n++;N in L;)N+=p
L[N]=p}}
```

The size:

```
$ wc -c x
97 x
```

The run (counting output lines instead of wasting space here) on a Thinkpad T60/T5500@1.6GHz in powersave mode (1 GHz clock, Debian6):

```
$ time mawk -f x | wc -l
78498

real    0m3.894s
user    0m3.820s
sys     0m0.072s
```

But since this won't be the shortest solution, speed is no matter.

The algorithm is a reorganized sieve method.
I have not seen this method elsewhere up to now and the local name is "floating sieve of erathosthenes" (FSOE) until I know better.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy - 65 chars

This feels like cheating, but... Output confirmed against other solutions (i.e. 'probable prime' is accurate for such small values)

```
n=new BigInteger(1);78498.times{println n=n.nextProbablePrime()}
```

The code uses the fact that there are 78498 primes that fit the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

### C# & LinqPad 71

As usual directly executable in LinqPad

```
for(int i=0;++i<1e6;){for(int b=1;++b<i;)if(i%b==0)goto a;i.Dump();a:;}
```

Takes about 7 minutes on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 35

```
use ntheory":all";print_primes(1e6)
```

Fast and small vs. the usual golf horrifically slow regex.  I used this earlier for 39 characters:

```
use ntheory":all";say for@{primes(1e6)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Golfscript, 55**

```
{.2<{}{:l;1{).l\%}do}if}:r;10 6?,{..r={" "+print}{}if}%
```

Old code:

```
{:q-2:r\,{1+}%{q\%0={1r+:r}{}if}%;;r}:f 1000000,{f!},\;(;n*
```

**WARNING.**
This program uses an *extremely* slow algorithm, it takes ~15 seconds for it to display the 1000 first primes and the time grows exponentially. If you want to use it, change the 1000000 in the code to something lower.

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
11+:aa*:\/&~!
:**=?;2&\
:v?=&:&:<^!?%&+1:&
.\:nao90
```

There's Befunge but no ><>, so I thought "might as well". Uses the ever so slow trial division.

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk - 22 characters

```
Integer primesUpTo:1e6
```

The dialect is Smalltalk/X; other dialects have the same or a similar method in Integer.

Exec. time (measured with: "Time millisecondsToRun:[...]" is 90ms on my somewhat older (2010) 2.6Ghz Mac.

Evaluating "(Integer primesUpTo:1e6) size" returns: 78498

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>118</s> 117 bytes

```
n=999984;t=true;a=[t]*n;(2..Math.sqrt(n).round).each{|i|a[i]&&(i..n/i).each{|j|a[j*i]=!t}};(2..n).each{|i|a[i]&&p(i)}
```

## Run Time:

```
0.53s user 0.13s system 92% cpu 0.714 total
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2, 79 bytes

Utilises the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```
var r=[Int](2..<Int(1e6));while r.count>0{print(r[0]);r=r.filter{$0%r[0] != 0}}
```

**Notes:**

- Solution without the sieve needs two extra bytes.
- Takes ~14 mins on i5 3.5 GHz; or ~40 secs if compiled with optimisations.
- Use `-O` flag with `swiftc` to turn on optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

## Molecule (v6+), 19 bytes

```
0{1+_p?~}u1000000L
```

Explanation:

```
0{1+_p?~}u1000000L
0{1+_p?~}          Push 0, add a code block.
         u1000000  Push one million.
                 L Repeat the code block 1000000 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 139 bytes

```sql
WITH v AS(SELECT LEVEL i FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1)SELECT a.i FROM v a, v b GROUP BY a.i HAVING:1-2=SUM(SIGN(MOD(a.i,b.i)))ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 107 Bytes, 26 minutes, naive approach

```
y->{int i=1,j,n,r=0;for(j=2,n=1000000;(r+=++i>=j?1:0)!=n;j+=j%i==0?i=1:0)System.out.print(i>=j?j+"\n":"");}
```

ungolfed

```
                y->{
                int i=1,j,n,r=0;
                for(j=2,n=1000000; 
                    (r+=((++i>=j)?1:0))!=n; 
                    j+=((j%i==0)?i=1:0)) {
                    System.out.print(i>=j?j+"\n":"");
                }
                }
```

Worstcase Runtime is `O(n)` divisons for primes as it tests everything in `[2,i[` and looks if anything divides `i` and prints it if it's divisorless or continues if a divisor is found. `n*O(n)` would make it `O(n^2)`, but due to distribution of divisors and primes, it is something along `O(n^2/log(n))+O(n*log(n))` divisons. In practice this takes something along 26 minutes apparently.

## Java ungolfed 1601 Bytes, adaptive wheel sieve, 1.6 seconds

```
public class Sieve {
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
    int target = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int product = 1;
    int nextEvolve = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;
    int iteration = 0;
    boolean evolve = true;
    Sieve(int n) {
        this.candidates.add(1);
        this.target = n;
    }
    int next() {
        final int toTest = this.product*this.multiplier+this.candidates.get(this.iteration);
        //System.out.println("try: "+toTest+" p:"+this.product+" m:"+this.multiplier+" i:"+this.iteration);
        for(int i = this.nextEvolve; i < this.primes.size() && toTest/this.primes.get(i)>=this.primes.get(i); ++i) {
            if(toTest%this.primes.get(i)==0) {
                ++this.iteration;
                if((this.iteration%=this.candidates.size())==0) {
                    ++this.multiplier;
                }
                return this.next();
            }
        }
        this.primes.add(toTest);
        ++this.iteration;
        if((this.iteration%=this.candidates.size())==0) {
            ++this.multiplier;
            if(this.evolve && this.multiplier%this.primes.get(this.nextEvolve)==0) {
                if(this.target/this.product<toTest) {
                    this.evolve = false;
                }else {
                    final int size = this.candidates.size();
                    for(int i = 1; i < this.primes.get(this.nextEvolve); i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                            if((i*this.product+this.candidates.get(j))%this.primes.get(this.nextEvolve)!=0) {
                                this.candidates.add(i*this.product+this.candidates.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    this.product*=this.primes.get(this.nextEvolve);
                    this.multiplier=this.multiplier/this.primes.get(this.nextEvolve);
                    ++this.nextEvolve;
                }
            }
        }
        return toTest;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Sieve s = new Sieve(1_000_000);
        for(int prime = s.next(); prime < 1_000_000; prime = s.next()) {
            System.out.println(prime);
        }
    }
}
```

## Java golfed 883 Bytes, 16 seconds

```
class S{ArrayList<Integer> p=new ArrayList<>(),c=new ArrayList<>();int t,q,n,m,i;boolean e=true;S(int n){this.c.add(1);this.t=n;q=m=1;n=i=0;}int next(){int toTest=this.q*this.m+this.c.get(this.i);for(int i=this.n;i<this.p.size();++i)if(toTest%this.p.get(i)==0){++this.i;if((this.i%=this.c.size())==0)++this.m;return this.next();}this.p.add(toTest);++this.i;if((this.i%=this.c.size())==0){++this.m;if(this.e && this.m%this.p.get(this.n)==0){if(this.t/this.q<toTest) this.e=false;else{int size=this.c.size();for(int i=1;i<this.p.get(this.n);i++)for(int j=0;j<size;j++)if((i*this.q+this.c.get(j))%this.p.get(this.n)!=0)this.c.add(i*this.q+this.c.get(j));this.q*=this.p.get(this.n);this.m=this.m/this.p.get(this.n);++this.n;}}}return toTest;}public static void main(String[] args){S s=new S(1_000_000);for(int prime=s.next();prime<1_000_000;prime=s.next()){System.out.println(prime);}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
V^T6IP_NN
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Explanation:

```
V   : Iterate over all numbers from 0 to ...  
^T6 : 10^6
I   : If ...  
P_N : number is prime ...  
N   : print number
```

Answer (score 0):

### Stata, 21 bytes

```
primes 1000000, clear
```

This is (obviously) a built-in command...

Answer (score 0):

## [ASMD](https://github.com/mcparadip/ASMD), 7 bytes

```
W(i|P?p
```

Explanation:

```
W        # Push 1,000,000
 (       # Begin range loop (0 -> 999,999)
  i      # Push counter variable
   |     # Duplicate
    P?p  # If prime, print
       . # Implicit end range loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

```
for n in 0..1e6
if('1'*n)!~/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
puts n
end
end
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147240/ruby-isprime-method) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 86 bytes

```python
for i in range(2,int(1e6)):
	if all([i%j!=0 for j in range(2,int(i**0.5)+1)]): print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ItqCyo/P8/Lb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDSCczr0TDMNVMU9OKizMzTSExJ0cjOlM1S9HWQAGkNgtdbaaWloGeqaa2oWasppVCQRFQTCHz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
ç►╪(Æ;Ç
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A7%E2%96%BA%E2%95%AA%28%C3%86%3B%C3%87&a=1)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
wi|6QVM<
w           loop
 i          loop index `i`
  |6        the `i`th prime
    Q       print and keep on stack
     VM<    while the printed number is less than one million
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II), 18 bytes

```
6E_s{ls1+v;(lP)}*h
```

Requires the latest version of the interpreter due to a bug in how the previous version handled addition with `null` values (although in retrospect it might work even in the previous version if you change `ls1+` to `1sl+`).

Approximate pseudocode translation:

```
x=0
Repeat 10⁶ times:
    x=x+1
    if x is prime:
        print x
End
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
►rg¶n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtF1F6Ye25f3/DwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
►     # Push 1000000
 r    # Pop and push a list in the range [0,1000000)
  g   # Filter it by:
   ¶  #  Is it a prime?
    n # Join with newline delimiter
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```