# Kolmogorov-mania

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

The [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of a string s is defined as the length of the *shortest program* P that outputs s. If the length of P is shorter than the length of s, then s is said to be *compressible*, otherwise s is *incompressible*. Most strings are incompressible ...

Write the shortest program that outputs this string (without spaces and without newlines):

```
d9 a6 b6 33 56 a7 95 4b 29 b0 ac 7f 2a aa 6d 19 b8 4b 4c f8 b6 2a ac 95 
a1 4b 4e a5 9d b3 e7 c9 4c 49 59 ec 94 b3 aa 6c 93 8f 11 5a 4d 39 75 82 
ec ea 24 cc d3 2d c3 93 38 4e b7 a6 0d d2 b5 37 23 54 ad 1b 79 aa 6e 49 
55 52 94 5a a7 3a 6a e9 e4 52 cd 2d 79 ad c6 12 b5 99 5b b4 76 51 17 4e 
94 f3 9a a2 e7 15 6a 55 14 4d 4e 4a a3 5c 2f ab 63 cc b5 a6 a4 92 96 8a 
2e c3 d8 88 9b 8c a9 16 f5 33 22 5b a2 e2 cc 1b 27 d4 e8 db 17 a4 39 85 
ca aa 5b 4f 36 24 d3 c6 f6 94 ad d7 0f 71 24 e1 b1 c5 ef 65 35 6c 8d d7 
1a 87 1e 25 df 5d c0 13 b2 6f 5a 57 28 98 bd 41 66 04 ed a2 52 c9 ac 83 
b3 6c 56 7e d1 c6 cc 53 4a 62 c5 59 a9 b2 d4 af 22 a5 a9 f4 b2 99 23 32 
f8 fb ae 48 6a 8a 9a b5 46 7a 36 59 9f 92 d3 25 b5 19 bd 8a 4a 49 62 a5 
e4 59 fb e5 ba a2 35 dd a9 36 1d a9 c9 69 89 77 6a b2 34 2d 1d 22 61 c5 
c2 66 1c e2 76 74 52 a5 d9 84 b9 8a a6 b5 14 ec 29 58 b2 bc 96 16 16 48 
f5 c5 bd 2f 32 1b 3d 4f 4b 2e b2 6b 9a d9 32 a4 4b 5c bc 92 b7 b3 26 39 
fa 42 2d 64 ed 1a 79 49 4c a3 b7 85 b2 a6 e2 8c d9 55 90 e1 a8 87 4b 60 
a6 e1 ba c4 bb ec 32 39 76 90 a6 b4 c6 65 79 61 91 aa 3d 54 b7 18 3d 15 
4b 06 db 30 8a 4d 4a a1 35 75 5d 3b d9 98 ac 55 5b 10 dd b3 e2 cc f1 5e 
b3 2b 53 90 b6 ee 2b ac 8f 88 8d 95 5a 75 df 59 2d 1c 5a 4c e8 f4 ea 48 
b9 56 de a0 92 91 a9 15 4c 55 d5 e9 3a 76 8e 04 ba e7 b2 aa e9 ab 2a d6 
23 33 45 3d c4 e9 52 e3 6a 47 50 ba af e4 e5 91 a3 14 63 95 26 b3 8b 4c 
bc aa 5a 92 7a ab ad a6 db 53 2e 97 06 6d ba 3a 66 49 4d 95 d7 65 c2 aa 
c3 1a 92 93 3f ca c2 6c 2b 37 55 13 c9 88 4a 5c 62 6b a6 ae cc de 72 94
```

The output should look like:

```
d9a6b63356a7954b29b0ac7f2aaa6d19b84b4cf8b62aac95a14b4e...7294
```

Note: no user input is allowed, nor web access, nor libraries (except the one required for printing the output).

**Edit I:** the sequence seems random ... but it turns out to be highly compressible handling a *little bit* of prime numbers ...

**Edit II:** Well done! I'll review the answers in the next hours, then assign the bounty.
This is my idea on how it could be solved:

1. If you try to compress the data you don't go far away ...
2. In internet you can find the (well-known?) [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) (OEIS) ;
3. trying the first hexadecimal digits `d9, a6, b6, 33, ...` (or their decimal representation) give no result;
4. but if you convert the numbers to binary (`1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0`) and searching them on OEIS, [you get this result](https://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0&language=english&go=Search).
5. As noted by Claudiu, I also gave a *little* hint in the question (Edit I above) ... :-)

**The winner is**: Peter Taylor (GolfScript, 50), with a special mention for Claudiu (Python, 92), the first who "solved" it.

Comment: How is this more interesting than other [tag:komogorov-complexity] questions?

Comment: @Doorknob: perhaps nothing ... at least until someone will post an answer :-)

Comment: Do I understand correctly we are allowed internet access?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think implicitly standard loopholes apply here. And for the asker: [link this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/7162) in the question

Comment: Note: googling the first few bytes finds nothing but this question.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a game of "Guess the constant"?

Comment: Funny thing...I can't copy+paste this string properly when all the spaces and newlines are removed

Comment: why this string in particular? is it random?

Comment: @xem presumable because it isn't very compressable...I can get it to 744 characters using `gzdeflate`

Comment: also, "shortest program", in bytes or in characters?

Comment: @xem: I assume 1 character = 1 byte.

Comment: This still seems like a hide-and-seek kind of challenge...."Do you see what I did there?" isn't really the same as code-golf

Comment: @DavidWilkins: do you suggest to reveal how to generate the sequence?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi wouldn't that change the challenge to "write this code shorter than I did" ?  I'm not sure what I'd recommend, other than using the meta sandbox (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi) to proof your challenge before posting it

Comment: The obvious standard tool is the inverse symbolic calculator, but that draws a complete blank for 0.8502000689828988668429023263735528272644799.

Comment: Don't give in the the peer pressure. This challenge has prompted me to learn something about cryptography. For that, I gave you an upvote.

Comment: Too bad you just changed the question... I had it in 139 with `import re,urllib.request as r;print(re.split('</?code>',r.urlopen('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24909').read().decode())[1])`

Comment: @MathieuRodic: "no web access" was one of the first edit :-)

Comment: @Rusher: don't worry, even if I give the solution it can be interesting; however I think that this is not the right place for mind-juggling puzzles :-)

Comment: Don't give the solution! People are working on it :-)

Comment: Has anyone tried converting this number from Hex to Decimal, then calculating prime factors? It's a 1200 digit number, so it shouldn't be that difficult, it just requires a decent computer and an app which can handle such huge numbers.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I'm more in the way of `print f(prime[i])%255`

Comment: I got the answer in 92 characters, but as soon as I post it the cat's out of the bag... what should I do? I could provide the sha-256 of the code and offer the code once an answer is accepted.

Comment: @Claudiu: yeah, I think you should post the hash and then wait a little. Maybe the OP can set a deadline!

Comment: I recommend a deadline as well

Comment: I have the answer in 98 characters in Python and 106 characters in Haskell. Should I still post them (well, their hashes) even though there's a shorter solution already?

Comment: @immibis: IMO you can post the Haskell one ... if you found "how to do it" you deserve some upvotes :-)

Comment: of course, if I only post the hash, there's no evidence that I didn't just post a random hex string

Comment: I think the contest should be in two parts. First part is a prize given to those who found the answer. Second part is a prize given to those who really know how to compress the code and generate the smallest. Right now, it's more of a "guess my algorithm" question, which excludes dullards like me, but also real code golfing pros, (which I'm not either), and those who know APL and the other terse languages (still not me).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - Factoring only has a real benefit if you express the number as products of powers of primes with a substantial number of powers > 1. The number (which we'll call N) has a few small factors, but then ends up with a 1152 digit composite which is way beyond our current capabilities of about 220 digits. You can also express N as p(n1)*p(n2)*... with p the prime function and n the ordinal (e.g. first prime p(1) = 2, second prime p(2) = 3, nth prime p(n)). This will compress to log(N/ln(N)) characters which is actually not much smaller than log(N) characters, so minimal compression!

Comment: @immibis: True but what'd be the point of that? Some ill-gotten rep points? This is supposed to be for fun =)

Comment: Is base conversion included under "*the [library] required for printing the output*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: no, sorry. The only library function allowed is the one used to print the output.

Comment: That is what I was wondering. Using libraries (and interpreters for that matter) is code being used to generate output. It all has to be counted I think.

Comment: PS. looking at answers so far, and ignoring machine code and microcode, it could be argued that only language constructs can be allowed - no libraries can be used unless their source code is counted as well. So richer languages are at an advantage. Even better if your chosen language has a print statement that supports hashing - which just isn't cricket.

Comment: @what do you mean with "print statement that support hashing?"

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: Oh I didn't realize that I can't use base-conversion functions.. I use `hex`, for example, which is a built-in (I don't import anything), but I also use `range` and `all`, which are the same status (also built-in functions).. my program won't win anyway but should I technically not have used any of those?

Comment: @philcolbourn: Hashing has nothing to do with solving the problem. It's just a proof to avoid releasing the code prior to the end of the contest.

Comment: @Claudiu: Well `hex` isn't a "library function", it's just built-in. So I think you're ok.

Comment: @Claudiu I really misunderstood these answers then, didn't I. I read them as finding a small message that when hashed gave resulting long string. But have I misunderstood Kolmogorov complexity as well?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi - My error. I thought all these hash functions were part of answers so I thought that only way to not count hashing code was for some language to include it in print function. I feel a bit silly now.

Comment: It was that easy to find in OEIS?! Aaargh. I converted to indexes `0,1,3,4,7,8,10,13,14,...`, tried simple linear transforms of that, tried working from the other end, tried inverting the mask (`2,5,6,9,11,12,15,...`) and finally found [A138970](http://oeis.org/A138970)... and then realised that my very first search on OEIS would have turned up [A138971](http://oeis.org/A138971) if I'd omitted the `0`.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Now that you've picked the winner, you should click the green tick on Peter Taylor's solution.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I accepted his answer; should I click on the +100, too or does the bounty automatically get assigend to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### GolfScript (50 bytes)

```
$ wc -c codegolf24909.min.gs 
50 codegolf24909.min.gs
$ md5sum codegolf24909.min.gs 
ce652060039fba071d17333a1199fd72  codegolf24909.min.gs
$ time golfscript.rb codegolf24909.min.gs 
d9a6b63356a7954b29b0ac7f2aaa6d19b84b4cf8b62aac95a14b4ea59db3e7c94c4959ec94b3aa6c938f115a4d397582ecea24ccd32dc393384eb7a60dd2b5372354ad1b79aa6e495552945aa73a6ae9e452cd2d79adc612b5995bb47651174e94f39aa2e7156a55144d4e4aa35c2fab63ccb5a6a492968a2ec3d8889b8ca916f533225ba2e2cc1b27d4e8db17a43985caaa5b4f3624d3c6f694add70f7124e1b1c5ef65356c8dd71a871e25df5dc013b26f5a572898bd416604eda252c9ac83b36c567ed1c6cc534a62c559a9b2d4af22a5a9f4b2992332f8fbae486a8a9ab5467a36599f92d325b519bd8a4a4962a5e459fbe5baa235dda9361da9c96989776ab2342d1d2261c5c2661ce2767452a5d984b98aa6b514ec2958b2bc96161648f5c5bd2f321b3d4f4b2eb26b9ad932a44b5cbc92b7b32639fa422d64ed1a79494ca3b785b2a6e28cd95590e1a8874b60a6e1bac4bbec32397690a6b4c665796191aa3d54b7183d154b06db308a4d4aa135755d3bd998ac555b10ddb3e2ccf15eb32b5390b6ee2bac8f888d955a75df592d1c5a4ce8f4ea48b956dea09291a9154c55d5e93a768e04bae7b2aae9ab2ad62333453dc4e952e36a4750baafe4e591a314639526b38b4cbcaa5a927aabada6db532e97066dba3a66494d95d765c2aac31a92933fcac26c2b375513c9884a5c626ba6aeccde7294

real    365m11.938s
user    364m45.620s
sys     0m6.520s
```

Since everyone else is now revealing their code, I will also pre-empt OP's request to unobfuscate:

```
38200,{:x,{)x\%!},,2=},4/{3\{2&!!1$++}/.57>39*+}%+
```

#### Overview dissection

- [Compute primes smaller than N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5987/194) with N=38200: this gives the first 4032 primes: `38200,{:x,{)x\%!},,2=},`
- We want one bit per prime, with a hex conversion, so split them into groups of 4: `4/`
- For each group, map each prime `p` to `p&2 != 0`, and do a base-2 to base-16 conversion: `{3\{2&!!1$++}/.57>39*+}%` (this is where the interesting tricks are)
- We now have an array of ASCII values, plus the empty string from stdin; concatenate them to get a single string for output: `+`

#### More detailed dissection of the base conversion

Given a stack holding an empty string and a list of primes, we need to do two conversions:

1. Convert each prime to a bit indicating whether it's equal to 2 or 3 (mod 4)
2. Convert the bits into hex digits

There are lots of equally long ways to do 1; e.g.

```
{4%1>}%
{4%2/}%
{2/1&}%
{2/2%}%
{2&!!}%
```

or even

```
{2&}% followed by a 2/ after the base conversion
```

For 2, the obvious approach is

```
2base 16base{'0123456789abcdef'=}%+
```

But base is a long word, and since 16 = 2<sup>4</sup> we can easily save a few chars with

```
4/{2base'0123456789abcdef'=}%+
```

Now the most obvious waste is the 18 chars devoted to that string. We just want a function from digit to ASCII code.
We want to map `0` to `'0' = 48`, ..., `9` to `'9' = 57`, `10` to `'a' = 97`, ... `15` to `'f' = 102`.

```
4/{2base.9>39*+48+}%+
```

But now throw into the mix a ban on `base`. We need to implement it ourselves. The obvious implementation (in this direction, the easy one) is that `k base` is a fold `{\k*+}*`. The slightly longer alternative is a straightforward iteration, which needs a base case: `0\{\k*+}/`. Base 2 is slightly special: `1$++` is equivalent to `\2*+` for the same length, and I've taken that approach.

Both of those are longer than the 5-char `2base`, but since we're now iterating over the values we can pull in part 1 to have a single loop. We replace

```
{2&!!}%4/{2base.9>39*+48+}%+
```

with

```
4/{{2&!!1$++}*.9>39*+48+}%+
```

for a nice 1-char saving, or

```
4/{0\{2&!!1$++}/.9>39*+48+}%+
```

for a 1-char loss.

But although that 1-char loss looks like a step backwards, consider what happens to that 0.
It's multiplied by 16 and added to the base-conversion output. And the final thing we do is to add a multiple of 16 to the output.
So we can combine the two as

```
4/{3\{2&!!1$++}/.57>39*+}%+
```

Joint shortest and the bonus cleverness makes it more interesting.

Comment: 360 minutes! That's quite a while. Wonder what approach you took.. mine takes <1 min

Comment: @Claudiu, I could make it a lot faster, but it would add about 5 characters, and this is [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] rather than code-golf with time constraints.

Comment: How much could you get it down if you used `base`? All the other solutions use an equivalent (mine uses `hex`, the C one uses `printf("%x")`, haskell uses `showHex`)

Comment: @Claudiu, actually my current best approach with `base` is longer than this one, because I did most of the optimisation after clarifying that I couldn't use it. `base` gives me a value from 0 to 15, so it still needs some work to convert to `0-9a-f`. I might revisit using `base` at some point, but not tonight.

Answer (score 32):

## Python, 92 characters

Here it is ladies and gentlemen, the code itself!

```
>>> code = "R=range;print hex(int(''.join(`i/2%2`for i in R(38198)if all(i%x for x in R(2,i))),2))[2:-1]"
>>> len(code)
92
>>> exec code
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
>>> import hashlib; hashlib.sha256(code).hexdigest()
'60fa293bbe895f752dfe208b7b9e56cae4b0c8e4cdf7c5cf82bf7bab60af3db6'
```

Marzio left a clever hint by saying that "it turns out to be highly compressible handling a *little bit* of prime numbers". I was sure the "little bit" wasn't italicized by accident, so I converted the hex string to bits and tried to find patterns. I thought that at first he was representing all the primes as bits and concatenating them together, but that didn't work out. Then maybe taking only a few digits, or dropping all the zeroes in the bit string - still no. Maybe it's a bitstring of the least-significant-bit of the first few primes? Not quite. But eventually I found the one that worked - it's a bitstring of the second-least-significant bit from the first however-many primes.

So, my code does just that: generate just enough primes, take the second bit of each (`i/2%2`), concatenate them as a binary string, then convert it to base-10 (`int(..., 2)`) and then to base-16 (`hex(...)`).

Comment: Great! I'm new to code golf, but the hash stuff is a good way to let other people have fun in discovering "how to do it". I'll wait two days, then open a bounty (that I'll reward on trust :).

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: Sure that works! Or maybe better to say you'll reward it on the day before the bounty is due, and if the winner doesn't reveal his answer the 2nd in place wins, etc... why rely on trust when you don't have to?

Comment: Why has code in hashlib not been counted? Isn't it code being run to generate output?

Comment: @philcolbourn: No the code doesn't use hashlib. It's just to generate the sha256 hash so tomorrow I can prove I wrote the code when I first posted this. You will see tomorrow!

Comment: @Claudiu: Now you should explain me how did you crack the problem! Well done!

Comment: @rubik: Hehe sure, I added the story behind it.

Answer (score 9):

## C, <s>136</s> <s>116</s> <s>109</s> 103 characters

OK then, here's my effort:

```
i;p;q;main(n){for(;n++,q<4032;){for(i=1;++i<n&&n%i;);if(i==n)p+=p+(n&2)/2,p=++q&3?p:printf("%x",p)*0;}}

MD5 hash = f638552ef987ca302d1b6ecbf0b50e66
```

Comment: Since `printf` returns the number of character written, which is always non-zero here, you can use `!printf(...)` instead of `printf(...)*0` to save one char.

Comment: @ace *\*slaps forehead\** Ah, why didn't I think of that?? Thanks ace, as always :-)  (May as well leave the code as it is, since it's supposed to match the MD5 hash.)

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 105

SHA1 hash: `a24bb0f4f8538c911eee59dfc2d459194ccb969c`

Output:

```
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
```

Edit: Code:

```
import Numeric;f(x:z)s=f[y|y<-z,0/=mod y x]$s*2+quot(mod x 4)2;f[]s=s;main=putStr$showHex(f[2..38198]0)""
```

I missed the rule about not using any library functions except for printing (putStr). I would assume that mathematical operators, while they're technically functions, are allowed.

Answer (score 7):

### JS, 764

if we consider this string as base64, we can have a smaller version using the un-base-64-ed version:

```
btoa("wÖºo­÷ç¦»÷ÛÖôiÎßÙ¦éÝ}oÎáÇüo­iÏyk^áæ¹õÖ÷{·=áÎ=ç×÷÷i®÷×^ZáÝýï6yÇÛw}swßÎo¶ºÑ×voûÛ~xiÝ[ïÖéî=çv÷Zk½Úé§½{vqÝïÖs­vo}å¶øï®u×¾÷÷õ¦¶{½yé®y×áîk~\Ùöëwoºkv÷¯Ùç7wÏ<õ¿kÝz÷Ûn[kg¶qÍ[Û·x{Ç[×¶¸ßß9q¦å¾ß­¸ww:¯xi×{ÑþõÛµoW9yþ¹ßñ×{Õ¯;Õí¹uþ]sMwonå®{ÛÏ|mÞ5ë­8yÖ¶çg=iÏ7o~ç®ÞwW:qÎwá®¶s}kÖöwÛf¹k×øoo}Û}öÇÛiî<é¯õ¦ùã®Úß®}õÿvw}¹o}mßá®=ëf¹{}}·¹m¦¶ß]kÝúÕÖ½sÞ½óÞûé¦ößÕÝ¶ëW9snºÕÇ¶ï®øçf¹wß8oßk¦ù×ÛÞ|ofÜ÷­z×®<9mÝßm[ÝÞá½onõ§}ßf¸á¾\mÏvo¶÷Û­ý}®6ÙÞ¸yÝZïÞ=áÆ·o¿9ofº{owÞy÷GµkÏ;á¾´k§µm§8m·ßmýï¯tk¦øs®¹ïÞµ÷VÝÞxo½|ÝÝyá½:u½ôñ®á¦µßùåÝÛwß|iÎyå½tuÖ÷{g^^o}çto§Ù¶ñÿ<ñßyå®ùuþ}ÙÝ\å®{Çøy®<oÞzuæ´÷oukÝyáÎyw½Ý®úñí8m§»of{ÖÙ§zÛ}÷ãÝs½çg·é®;çFÚi÷¸{uk}xëyÛ¦÷ñ¾mÆå¯ví¦iÖºu¾wÙï{Ó®m­Úë®=áßyw¾¹sfs}Z÷owÝ÷snÙ½ûçwsß<á®\ënk¦qÇ^ïox")
```

But I think that the author wants us to find the logic behind this non-random string instead.

Comment: to avoid the "downvotes rush" I added some details in the question :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathetmatica - 56

The mystery is already solved, so just implementing the idea

```
⌊.5Prime@Range@4032⌋~Mod~2~FromDigits~2~IntegerString~16
```

Comment: Nice. I'm curious what the shortest possibility is now that the cat's out of the bag

Comment: Do you call that "no libraries (except the one required for printing the output)"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yep, no imports - no libraries.

Comment: Judging by the comments, I don't think that's how OP intended it to be interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

## J - 46 char

Don't mind me, just logging the J golf here for posterity. Wasn't clever enough to figure out the trick.

```
4[1!:2&4'0123456789abcdef'{~#.2|<.-:p:i.1007 4
```

Explained:

- `p:i.1007 4` - Create a 1007-row, 4-column matrix of the integers from 0, then take the prime numbers corresponding to those integers. Yes, `p:` is a J builtin. Yes, we're four primes short.
- `2|<.-:` - Halve each number (`-:`), floor it (`<.`), and take that modulo 2 (`2|`). This is the same as taking the next-to-lease significant bit.
- `#.` - Convert each row of the result from base 2 into an integer. This gives us 1007 numbers from 0 to 15 inclusive.
- `'0123456789abcdef'{~#.` - Take each row of this matrix of bits as the binary for a number, and use that number to select from the list of hex digits. This converts every four bits into the hex.
- `1!:2&4` - The J interpreter has a problem with outputting strings longer than 256 chars, so we have to send this data directly to stdout. You win some, you lose some.
- `4[` - Finally, discard the result from `1!:2` and instead output the missing 4 from the output. We do this because it's shorter than including those last four primes and returning an empty result here.

Answer (score 0):

## JS, 503

Following @xem idea:

```
s='Ù¦¶3V§K)°¬*ªm¸KLø¶*¬¡KN¥³çÉLIYì³ªlZM9uìê$ÌÓ-Ã8N·¦\nÒµ7#T­yªnIURZ§:jéäRÍ-y­Æµ[´vQNó¢çjUMNJ£\/«cÌµ¦¤.ÃØ©õ3"[¢âÌ'+"'"+'ÔèÛ¤9Êª[O6$ÓÆö­×q$á±Åïe5l×%ß]À²oZW(½Afí¢RÉ¬³lV~ÑÆÌSJbÅY©²Ô¯"¥©ô²#2øû®HjµFz6YÓ%µ½JIb¥äYûåº\n5Ý©6©Éiwj²4-"aÅÂfâvtR¥Ù¹¦µì)X²¼HõÅ½/2=OK.²kÙ2¤K\¼·³&9úB-díyIL£·²¦âÙUá¨K`¦áºÄ»ì29v¦´Æeyaª=T·=KÛ0MJ¡5u];Ù¬U[Ý³âÌñ^³+S¶î+¬ZußY-ZLèôêH¹VÞ ©LUÕé:vºç²ªé«*Ö#3E=ÄéRãjGPº¯äå£c&³L¼ªZz«­¦ÛS.mº:fIM×eÂªÃ?ÊÂl+7UÉJ\bk¦®ÌÞr'
r=''
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) r+=s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 55

```
Prime~Array~4031~BitAnd~2~FromDigits~2~IntegerString~16
```

Tested on Mathematica 8. This makes use of two observations:

- Mathematica's `FromDigits` doesn't actually check the range of the digits given, so if you apply it to a list of the form `{2,0,2,2,0,...}` you just get twice the result as if applying to `{1,0,1,1,0,...}`. But that's exactly the form generated by `BitAnd`ing the primes with 2.
- The last bit of the number whose hexadecimal representation we want happens to be zero (as evidenced by the string ending in an even digit), so it is just two times the number you'd get with one prime less. But a factor of two is exactly what we get from using the previous observation, so everything perfectly fits together.