# Primes numbers with prime index

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

Write a program or function that outputs/returns the first 10000 prime-indexed prime numbers.

If we call the n<sup>th</sup> prime `p(n)`, this list is

```
3, 5, 11, 17, 31, 41, 59 ... 1366661
```

because

```
p(p(1)) = p(2) = 3
p(p(2)) = p(3) = 5
p(p(3)) = p(5) = 11
p(p(4)) = p(7) = 17
...
p(p(10000)) = p(104729) = 1366661
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden, and standard output methods are allowed. You may answer with a full program, a named function, or an anonymous function.

Comment: You should generally try to post challenges in the sandbox first (see the link on the right side) in order to work out the issues.

Comment: Optimizing for runtime is not what we do in a code-golf challenge; the shortest program always wins.

Comment: Primes with prime subscripts: [A006450](https://oeis.org/A006450).

Comment: @bilbo Answers for code golf are usually accepted after a week, and should be accepted as the _shortest_ successful code. If you wanted code _speed_, there is a tag for that. See [this page about the tag code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).

Comment: The answer you accepted isn't even the fastest. My Matlab/Octave answer runs in 0.16 seconds, and I'd imagine the (winning by size) J answer by @ZGarb has a similar runtime.

Comment: So weird I just did this the other day for a different reason in excel haha, small world of tasks

Comment: @ThomasKwa: I was surprised by seeing my answer as accepted one too. Maybe that decision can be undone? I would prefer that! And when it comes to speed, please distinguish solutions calculating the primes themself and the ones depending on preexisting prime functions or tables. I  think, this challenge should be reworked/reworded and/or split into different variants with different rules or whatever it takes to clearness and fairness...

Comment: I'm new here and in my opinion, I thought the solutions execution time must be taken in consideration in shorten contests. I have attended more solutions in conventional languages. Perhaps can I add a tag related to speed but there is only fastest-algorithm and fastest-code and I attended also a shorten solution. Is it possible to remove the accepted flag for more time to the contest?

Comment: @bilbo It's considered bad practice to change the winning criterion of the contest after answers have already been posted. If you want to create a new contest scored by something other than [tag:code-golf] (shortest code), post it in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first. (In its current form, in my opinion, this challenge wouldn't be a good fit for fastest-code or fastest-algorithm, so you'd need to change something else about it too.)

Comment: All contests need an *objective* winning criterion; they are off topic otherwise. If you're going to judge answers by size *and* speed, you need to disclose a way to combine both. This should be done when the contest is posted, not 14 hours and 10 answers later. I have undone all speed-related edits, since the only other option would be to close this post for being off topic.

Comment: Now we need to do this recursively, so we can see which number is prime indexed the longest.

Answer (score 17):

## MATLAB/Octave, 25 bytes

```
p=primes(2e6)
p(p(1:1e4))
```

It doesn't get much more straightforward than this.

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 72 bytes

```python
P=p=1;l=[]
while p<82e5/6:l+=P%p*[p];P*=p*p;p+=1
for x in l:print l[x-1]
```

This terminates with a "list index out of range error" after printing the 10000 numbers, which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/20260).

Uses the [Wilson's Theorem method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260) to generate a list `l` of the primes up to the 10000th prime. Then, prints the primes with the positions in the list, shifted by 1 for zero-indexing, until we run out of bounds after the 10000th prime-th prime.

Conveniently, the upper bound of `1366661` can be estimated as `82e5/6` which is `1366666.6666666667`, saving a char.

I'd like a single-loop method, printing prime-indexed primes as we add them, but it seems to be longer.

```python
P=p=1;l=[]
while p<104730:
 l+=P%p*[p]
 if len(l)in P%p*l:print p
 P*=p*p;p+=1
```

Comment: This is way better than the garbage I was writing. +1

Comment: This only prints 1229 numbers

Comment: @aditsu I think I see my mistake. Are you able to run this code with the bigger bound?

Comment: It will probably take a long time :p

Comment: I think it finished ＼（＠；◇；＠）／ , it seems correct

Answer (score 9):

### J, 11 bytes

```
p:<:p:i.1e4
```

Outputs the primes in the format

```
3 5 11 17 31 41 59 67 83 109 127 ...
```

### Explanation

```
        1e4  Fancy name for 10000
      i.     Integers from 0 to 9999
    p:       Index into primes: this gives 2 3 5 7 11 ...
  <:         Decrement each prime (J arrays are 0-based)
p:           Index into primes again
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 65 bytes

```
p=[x|x<-[2..],all((>0).mod x)[2..x-1]]
f=take 10000$map((0:p)!!)p
```

Outputs: `[3,5,11,17,31,41,59,67,83,109,127.....<five hours later>...,1366661]`

Not very fast. How it works: `p` is the infinite list of primes (naively checking all `mod x y`s for y in `[2..x-1]`) . Take the first `10000` elements of the list you get when `0:p!!` (get nth element of `p`) is mapped on `p`. I have to adjust the list of primes where I take the elements from by prepending one number (-> `0:`), because the index function (`!!`) is zero based.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
Prime@Prime@Range@1*^4&
```

Pure function returning the list.

Comment: Prime is `Listable` so a simple `Prime@Prime@Range@1*^4&` will do

Comment: I know the feeling ... In any case, I think this is the prettiest Mathematica solution I have seen on here!

Comment: Let me guess, the `@` operator has higher precedence than `^` when writing `Range@10^4`? That's classic Mathematica messing up your game of golf. Good trick!

Answer (score 4):

## AWK - 129 bytes

...oookay... too long to win points for compactness... but maybe it can gain some honor for the speed?

The `x` file:

```
BEGIN{n=2;i=0;while(n<1366662){if(n in L){p=L[n];del L[n]}else{P[p=n]=++i;if(i in P)print n}j=n+p;while(j in L)j=j+p;L[j]=p;n++}}
```

Running:

```
$ awk -f x | nl | tail
  9991  1365913
  9992  1365983
  9993  1366019
  9994  1366187
  9995  1366327
  9996  1366433
  9997  1366483
  9998  1366531
  9999  1366609
 10000  1366661
```

Readable:

```
BEGIN {
        n=2
        i=0
        while( n<1366662 ) {
                if( n in L ) {
                        p=L[n]
                        del L[n]
                } else {
                        P[p=n]=++i
                        if( i in P ) print n
                }
                j=n+p
                while( j in L ) j=j+p
                L[j]=p
                n++
        }
}
```

The program computes a stream of primes using `L` as "tape of numbers" holding found primes jumping around on `L` to flag the nearby numbers already known to have a divisor. These jumping primes will advance while the "tape of numbers" `L` is chopped off number by number from its beginning.

While chopping off the tape head `L[n]` being empty means there is no known (prime) divisor.

`L[n]` holding a value means, this value is a prime and known to divide `n`.

So either we have found a prime divisor or a new prime.
Then ths prime will be advanced to the next `L[n+m*p]` on the tape found being empty.

This is like the Sieve of Eratosthenes "pulled thru a Klein's bottle". You always act on the tape start. Instead of firing multiples of primes thru the tape, you use the primes being found already as cursors jumping away from the tape start by multiple distances of their own value until a free position is found.

While the outer loop generates one prime or not prime decission per loop, the primes found get counted and stored in `P` as key, the value of this (key,value) pair is not relevant for the program flow.

If their key `i` happens to be in `P` already (`i in P`), we have a prime of the p(p(i)) breed.

Running:

```
$ time awk -f x.awk | wc -l
10000

real    0m3.675s
user    0m3.612s
sys     0m0.052s
```

Take into account that this code does not use external precalculated prime tables.

Time taken on my good old Thinkpad T60, so I think it deserves to be called fast.

Tested with `mawk` and `gawk` on Debian8/AMD64

Comment: good 129 bytes in gawk: now with Debian10/AMD64 on my corei7-i870@3.6Ghz:
real 0m2,417s
user 0m2,205s
sys 0m0,042s

Comment: you can save one byte with: BEGIN{n=2;i=0;while(n<1366662){if(n in L){p=L[n];del L[n]}else{P[p=n]=++i;if(i in P)print n}j=n+p;while(j in L)j+=p;L[j]=p;n++}}

Answer (score 3):

## PARI/GP, 25 bytes

```
apply(prime,primes(10^4))
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 19

```
3D#{mp},_1e4<:(\f=p
```

You can [try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=3D%23%7Bmp%7D%2C_1e4%3C%3A(%5Cf%3Dp), but you'll need a little patience :p

For the record, the last number is 1366661.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

**(or [<s>6</s> 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBbmKRzYU/P8PAA) to list the first 10,000 prime-indexed prime numbers, followed by [the infinite number of] all the rest of them)**

*Thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) and [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) for suggesting the <s>6</s> 5-byte version!*

```
↑!4İ⁰Ṡm!İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr///ihpEhNMSw4oGw4bmgbSHEsHD//w) (unfortunately times-out on [TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbREWTIxseNW7IVTyyoQCI/v8HAA) before printing all 10,000 prime-indexed primes, but at least outputs what it's found so far...)

```
↑!4İ⁰Ṡm!İp
↑               # print the first
 !4             # 4th index of
   İ⁰           # powers of 10 (so, the first 10,000), of
     Ṡ          # hook: apply function to its own argument
      m!        # map index function to
        İp      # prime numbers
                # (implied by hook) to prime numbers
```

Comment: Nice answer. The 10000 primes restriction is a shame - too many bytes are wasted on that.

Comment: If you output an infinite list, it will still have the first 10000 items ;)

Comment: @user & Razetime - thanks for the suggestion from both of you - I've incorporated it (& credited you both)!

Comment: It didn't actually occur to me to print an infinite list - that's all Razetime, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 55 bytes

```perl
use ntheory':all';forprimes{print nth_prime$_,$/}104729
```

---

Uses [@DanaJ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30069/danaj)'s `Math::Prime::Util` module for perl (loaded with the pragma `ntheory`). Get it with:

```perl
cpan install Math::Prime::Util
cpan install Math::Prime::Util::GMP
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èj ©°Tj}jL²
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yGogqbBUan1qTLI)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>76</s> 109 bytes - disqualified -  requalified?

edit: I am sorry, I was going for primes but missed the putting, didn´t reach the goal of "primes with primeindex". Your are free to grab and enhance. I'll be glad to be learning from you.

Based on Wilson Theorem

```
def p(x):
 c=n=2
 for i in range(3,x):
  c*=i-1
  if c%i!=0:
   print(n,i)
   n+=1
```

### without index, 62 bytes

```
def p(x):
 c=2
 for i in range(3,x):
  c*=i-1
  if c%i!=0:print(i)
```

Anyone can give me an example or good link, how to make a lambda function from it?

### edit: just to have it done right: 109bytes

```
def p(x):
 c=n=2
 p=[2]
 for i in range(2,x):
  c*=i-1
  if c%i!=0:
   p.append(i)
   if n in p: print(p[-1])
   n+=1
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  Your functions seem to output all prime numbers (and the first one precedes them with an index).  The question defines 'prime-indexed prime numbers' as those in the list of all primes that have an index value that is also a prime.  For instance, 7 - the 4th prime - isn't prime-indexed because 4 isn't a prime...

Comment: I am sorry. You are right, I misunderstood it :( Thank you very much for spending your time on clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `H`, <s>8 7 6</s> 5 bytes

Saved 1 + 1 bytes thanks to Aaron Miller

```
²ʀǎ‹ǎ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=H&code=%C2%B2%CA%80%C7%8E%E2%80%B9%C7%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
H flag - Push 100 to the stack
²ʀǎƛ‹ǎ
²        Squared (10,000)
 ʀ       Range [0, 10,000)
  ǎ      Map each a in that range to the ath prime
   ‹     Decrement each, because the challenge uses 1-indexing
    ǎ    Get the nth prime for each of those
```

Comment: [7 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%81%C2%B2%CA%80%C7%8E%C6%9B%E2%80%B9%C7%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller Thanks, forgot about auto-closing!

Comment: I completely forgot about the `H` tag, which presets the stack to 100, allowing for [5 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=H&code=%C2%B2%CA%80%C7%8E%E2%80%B9%C7%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 7 bytes (non-competing)

Code:

```
4°L<Ø<Ø
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MsKwTDzDmDzDmA&input=), **note** that I have changed the `4` into a `2`. If you have a lot of time, you can change the `2` back to `4`, but this will take a *lot* of time. I need to fasten the algorithm for this.

Explanation:

```
4°       # Push 10000 (10 ^ 4)
  L      # Create the list [1 ... 10000]
   <     # Decrement on every element, [0 ... 9999]
    Ø    # Compute the nth prime
     <   # Decrement on every element
      Ø  # Compute the nth prime
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ȷ4RÆN⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdpOgw21@jxp3/f8PAA)

Obviously, this times out on TIO. [Here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdpNDWw@3@T1q3PVwZ4vm//8A) is a version that prints as it goes, which reaches \$57493\$ (the \$765\$th term) before timing out

### How it works

```
ȷ4RÆN⁺ - Main link. Takes no arguments
ȷ4     - 10000
  R    - [1, 2, 3, ..., 9999, 10000]
     ⁺ - Do twice:
   ÆN  -   n'th prime of each
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
тnp<Ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YlPe4dYCm8Mz/v8HAA)

```
     Ø  # prime numbers with...
    <   # 1-based...
     Ø  # indices in...
  Åp    # first...
т       # 100...
 n      # ^ 2...
  Åp    # primes
        # implicit output
```