# A curious prime fraction formula

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, primes

Given a positive integer \$n\$ output the integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ (forming **reduced** fraction \$a/b\$) such that:

$$\frac a b = \prod ^n _{k=1} \frac {p^2_k - 1} {p^2_k + 1}$$

Where \$p_k\$ is the \$k\$ th prime number (with \$p_1 = 2\$).

Examples:

```
1   -> 3, 5
2   -> 12, 25
3   -> 144, 325
4   -> 3456, 8125
5   -> 41472, 99125
15  -> 4506715396450638759507001344, 11179755611058498955501765625
420 -> very long
```

Probabilistic prime checks are allowed, and it's ok if your answer fails due to limitations in your language's integer type.

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we also output `3.0` instead of `3`?

Comment: @AandN I guess... Make sure your program is correct for __all__ inputs though, and does not suffer from floating point errors for big inputs.

Comment: Can we output `a` and `b` as a rational type?

Comment: @AlexA. Only if the output clearly shows both integers.

Comment: @Dennis For this challenge I'll be lenient (poke around in chat history for discussion around this) and remove restrictions.

Comment: "it's ok if your answer fails due to limitations in your language's integer type" TODO: write a language with a 1 bit integer type...

Comment: @SamYonnou Those already exist, but [abusing native number types to trivialize a problem](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8245) is one of the loopholes that are forbidden by default.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the original post, but `a/b` converges on 2/5. More info here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164092/computing-prod-p-fracp2-1p21-without-the-zeta-function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 9 bytes

```
RÆN²‘İḤCP
```

[Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=UsOGTsKy4oCYxLDhuKRDUA&input=&args=MTU)

#### Trivia

Meet M!

M is a fork of Jelly, aimed at mathematical challenges. The core difference between Jelly and M is that M uses infinite precision for all internal calculations, representing results symbolically. Once M is more mature, Jelly will gradually become more multi-purpose and less math-oriented.

M is very much work in progress (full of bugs, and not really *that* different from Jelly right now), but it works like a charm for this challenge and I just couldn't resist.

#### How it works

```
RÆN²‘İḤCP  Main link. Argument: n

R          Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 ÆN        Compute the kth primes for each k in that range.
   ²‘      Square and increment each prime p.
     İ     Invert; turn p² + 1 into the fraction 1 / (p² + 1).
      Ḥ    Double; yield 2 / (p² + 1).
       C   Complement; yield 1 - 2 / (p² + 1).
        P  Product; multiply all generated differences.
```

Comment: Is `ÆN` the only M-specific operator? Also Melly

Comment: None of these operators are specific to M. The difference is that M calculates a fraction, while Jelly calculates a floating point number.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
1##&@@(1-2/(Prime@Range@#^2+1))&
```

An unnamed function that takes integer input and returns the actual fraction.

This uses the fact that `(p2-1)/(p2+1) = 1-2/(p2+1)`. The code is then golfed thanks to the fact that Mathematica threads all basic arithmetic over lists. So we first create a list `{1, 2, ..., n}`, then retrieve all those primes and plug that list into the above expression. This gives us a list of all the factors. Finally, we multiply everything together by applying `Times` to the list, which can be golfed to `1##&`.

Alternatively, we can use `Array` for the same byte count:

```
1##&@@(1-2/(Prime~Array~#^2+1))&
```

Comment: `1-2`=`1`, right?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Yeah (`-1` actually), but `1-2/x ≠ -1/x`. ;)

Comment: `@Range@`±`~Array~`

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b731BZWc3BQcNQ10hfW1s7oCgzN9UhKDEvPdVBOc5IU@0/UCSvJFpZ1y7NQTlWrS44OTGvrprLUIfLSIfLWIfLRIfLVIfLEIhNjAy4av8DAA)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 106 bytes

```py
from fractions import*
n=input()
F=k=P=1
while n:b=P%k>0;n-=b;F*=1-Fraction(2*b,k*k+1);P*=k*k;k+=1
print F
```

The first and fourth lines hurt so much... it just turned out that using `Fraction` was better than multiplying separately and using `gcd`, even in Python 3.5+ where `gcd` resides in `math`.

Prime generation adapted from @xnor's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/21487), which uses Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>122</s> <s>77</s> 65 bytes

Thanks to Sherlock for shaving off 10 bytes.

```
require'prime'
->n{Prime.take(n).map{|x|1-2r/(x*x+1)}.reduce(:*)}
```

Defines an anonymous function that takes a number and returns a `Rational`.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <del>26</del> 25

```
/RiFN=N*MCm,tdhd^R2.fP_ZQ
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FRiFN%3DN%2aMCm%2Ctdhd%5ER2.fP_ZQ&input=420&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A15&debug=0) or run the [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FRiFN%3DN%2aMCm%2Ctdhd%5ER2.fP_ZQ&input=15&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A15%0A420&debug=0).

1 byte saved thanks to Jakube!

Pretty naive implementation of the specifications. Uses the spiffy "new" (I have no idea when this was added, but I've never seen it before) `P<neg>` which returns whether the positive value of a negative number is prime or not. Some of the mapping, etc can probably be golfed...

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes

```
n->prod(i=1,n,1-2/(prime(i)^2+1))
```

Alternate version (46 bytes):

```
n->t=1;forprime(p=2,prime(n),t*=1-2/(p^2+1));t
```

Non-competing version giving the floating-point (`t_REAL`) result (38 bytes):

```
n->prodeuler(p=2,prime(n),1-2/(p^2+1))
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
RÆN²µ’ż‘Pµ÷g/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsOGTsKywrXigJnFvOKAmFDCtcO3Zy8&input=&args=MTU) Thanks to @Dennis for -1 byte.

```
R                       Range [1..n]
 ÆN                     Nth prime
   ²                    Square
    µ                   Start new monadic chain
     ’ż‘                Turn each p^2 into [p^2-1, p^2+1]
        P               Product
         µ              Start new monadic chain
          ÷             Divide by...
           g/           Reduce GCD
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>59</s> 42 bytes

```
n->prod(1-big(2).//-~primes(2n^2)[1:n].^2)
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a `Rational` with `BigInt` numerator and denominator.

We begin by generating the list of prime numbers less than 2*n*<sup>2</sup> and selecting the first *n* elements. This works because the *n*th prime is always less than *n*<sup>2</sup> for all *n* > 1. ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092552/151436).)

For each *p* of the *n* primes selected, we square *p* using elementwise power (`.^2`), and construct the rational 2 / (*p* + 1), where 2 is first converted to a `BigInt` to ensure sufficient precision. We subtract this from 1, take the product of the resulting array of rationals, and return the resulting rational.

Example usage:

```
julia> f = n->prod(1-big(2).//-~primes(2n^2)[1:n].^2)
(anonymous function)

julia> f(15)
4506715396450638759507001344//11179755611058498955501765625
```

Saved 17 thanks to Sp3000!

Answer (score 2):

### Convex, 28 bytes

Convex is a new language that I am developing that is heavily based on CJam and Golfscript. The interpreter and IDE can be found [here](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex). Input is an integer into the command line arguments. Indexes are one-based. Uses the CP-1252 encoding.

```
,:)_{µ²1-}%×\{µ²1+}%×¶_:Ðf/p
```

You may or may not consider this answer to be competing since I was working on a few features that this program uses before the challenge was posted, but the commit was made once I saw this challenge go out.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 18 bytes

```
:Yq2^tqpwQpZd1Mhw/
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OllxMl50cXB3UXBaZDFNaHcv&input=Mw)

Fails for large inputs because only integers up to `2^52` can be accurately represented internally.

#### Explanation

```
:     % implicitly take input n. Generate range [1,...,n]
Yq    % first n prime numbers
2^    % square
tqp   % duplicate. Subtract 1. Product
wQp   % swap. Add 1. Product
Zd    % gcd of both products
1M    % push the two products again
h     % concatenate horizontally
w/    % swap. Divide by previously computed gcd. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Times@@Array[(Prime@#^2-1)/(Prime@#^2+1)&,#]&
```

Primes? Fractions? Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 53 bytes

Anonymous function, **53** characters:

```
(scanl(*)1[1-2%(p*p+1)|p<-nubBy(((>1).).gcd)[2..]]!!)
```

Try it [here](https://tryhaskell.org/) (note: in standard GHCi you need first to make sure `Data.Ratio` and `Data.List` are imported):

```
λ (scanl(*)1[1-2%(p*p+1)|p<-nubBy(((>1).).gcd)[2..]]!!) 5
41472 % 99125
:: Integral a => Ratio a
```

Haskell's list indexing `!!` is 0-based. `(___!!)` is an *operator section*, forming an anonymous function so that `(xs !!) n == xs !! n`.

It's four bytes less to generate the whole sequence:

```
λ mapM_ print $ take 10 $     -- just for a nicer output
    scanl(*)1[1-2%(n*n+1)|n<-[2..],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]]
1 % 1
3 % 5
12 % 25
144 % 325
3456 % 8125
41472 % 99125
3483648 % 8425625
501645312 % 1221715625
18059231232 % 44226105625
4767637045248 % 11719917990625
:: IO ()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_j}jU £[X²ÉX²Ä]ÃyÈ×ÃË÷Fry
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=X2p9alUgo1tYsslYssRdw3nI18PL90ZyeQ&input=NQotUQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
ʁǎ²₍‹›vΠ:ġḭ  # main program
```

```
ʁ            # range 0 to input
 ǎ²          # ith prime, sqaured
   ₍‹›       # push the increment and decrement of that list wrapped
      vΠ     # take the product of both lists
        :ġ   # duplicate, get the gcd
          ḭ  # divide both numbers by the gcd, print implicitly
```

I don't think the strategy of 1-2/p^2-1 works in Vyxal because it would just end with a floating point number rather than a fraction, but feel free to prove me wrong. (If it did work, it would be a literal translation from Dennis' M answer, but with a byte shaved off for the nth primes, coming out to 8)

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%81%C7%8E%C2%B2%E2%82%8D%E2%80%B9%E2%80%BAv%CE%A0%3A%C4%A1%E1%B8%AD&inputs=15&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 25 bytes

```
,r`PªD;⌐k`M┬`π`Mi│g;)@\)\
```

Outputs `a\nb` (`\n` is a newline). Large inputs will take a long time (and might fail due to running out of memory) because prime generation is pretty slow.

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LHJgUMKqRDvijJBrYE3ilKxgz4BgTWnilIJnOylAXClc&input=Mw)

Explanation:

```
,r`PªD;⌐k`M┬`π`Mi│g;)@\)\
,r                         push range(input)
  `PªD;⌐k`M                map:
   P                         k'th prime
    ª                        square
     D                       decrement
      ;                      dupe
       ⌐                     add 2 (results in P_k + 1)
        k                    push to list
           ┬               transpose
            `π`M           map product
                i│         flatten, duplicate stack
                  g;)      push two copies of gcd, move one to bottom of stack
                     @\    reduce denominator
                       )\  reduce numerator
```

Comment: The title looks hilarious. I read it as "Seriously, 25 bytes ?! "

Comment: @AlexKChen It's been nearly 2 years since I created the language, and it's just now paid off :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
Πmo§/→←□↑İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr///OoG1vwqcv4oaS4oaQ4pah4oaRxLBw////MTU)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
[:*/1-2%1+*:@p:@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxqwIxAIP3/oogPA61dzZt014LiiA4Obk6iqIu7w1v8N@fd5xDIPlI8hoWXXPHtqKBhUMd1XY4nE/H4VJXG7b@h@tV3f/V/bMbluZ2ffzivljjXUF4BEQIlLm9n/9NYwig3SFYyPjZ01t4mfBNMVqEMcdvMypZ9ByJZhIZ8zgpZWLUzORSpkJJkwt9VpHLzjFMdyRzyVIinfpY@iLJMSclr@ED)

Uses the same formula that Martin Ender's answer does.