# Print Gobar Primes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, primes

Gobar primes ([A347476](https://oeis.org/A347476)) are numbers which give a prime number when 0's and 1's are interchanged in their binary representation.

For example, \$10 = 1010_2\$, and if we flip the bits, we get \$0101_2 = 5\$ which is prime. Therefore, 10 is a Gobar prime

As simple as that: print the series with any delimiter. Shortest code wins.

Comment: Do we need to print the series, or can we use the normal [tag:sequence] rules (taking an index as input and printing that item)? Also, I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges, it helps a lot!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms print the series
BTW index one could be proposed right?

Comment: You might want to check out the [default sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info), those are what most challenges allow.

Comment: Weird to call those numbers (Gobar) primes when only one of them is prime

Comment: The sequence rules for I/O (choose to either output the nth, first n or all) do apply by default to [sequence] challenges, but I would suggest clarifying that in the post

Comment: @luismendo it's a sequence.

Comment: @LuisMendo Any odd prime will give an even number when flipped, so there are no primes in the sequence

Comment: @PurkkaKoodari Yes, that's what I said; except for one ( `5` is the only prime in the sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `5`, 6 bytes

```
∞'b⌐Bæ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%E2%88%9E%27b%E2%8C%90B%C3%A6&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

this just times out, so not sure if it is valid

```
∞   # All positive integers
'       # filter by
b      # binary
⌐      # Minus from 1, (1-1=0, 1-0=1, genius)
B     # decimal
æ    # is prime?
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `5`, 8 bytes

```
∞ƛb⌐Bæß,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%E2%88%9E%C6%9Bb%E2%8C%90B%C3%A6%C3%9F%2C&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

This one actually prints everything (remove the 5 flag to run for more time)

pseudo code

```
all positive integers
map
  binary representation
  subtract each bit from 1 aka complement
  back to decimal
  is prime
  if truthy
    print
  (implicit else)
    (implicit continue)
(implicit end map)
```

Comment: Probably don't put `5` in the header if you're just using it to keep it from infinitely looping

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>96</s></sup> 94 bytes

```c
k;i;d;p;f(n){for(i=5;n;n-=p)for(k=i++^(1<<32-__builtin_clz(i))-1,d=p=k>1;++d<k;)p=p&&k%d;--i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHtbsIwDPy/p4iQQCltNZJ@0CqEP9OeYjDE2pRFZaWinYZAvPq6cwdsVLJzd3Zqx878TZZ1XamsylWtCl45p2K351ZHqlKVr2uHaKmt675yMZsF0l@t3j7ttrXVKtseuXUcX3i5rnU5F8p181mpnFrXo1E5zJXvW3XubNWyj7WtuMNODwwfCeZQm6w1@cuSaXYKPRZ5LPGYmMAkLICBS3CJqIxhxFOPBYgH0ELEQjoRi4Aj6BFh5MXgsYCBx@BT5CXQEjqhpcApnX3NkByhvrwgKmJqpO@G2qEehIzIUV5IGtUVIVGqLCJKodqCioopaVNCCSEqLBKKpoSotpxIcvQqIc@qH032vt6P4U1Wmv3vbAaLw7NcHNInWDTw2H8eDC73sCbGaa62ys0B1ybqAmessUezK/h14s7jRRjfFMVct8@@bui6pRZ/6gPqTm4gF7x17lUD9bbW/tbyL6HeI6Xgg2HO/DmDHzaLCq9pPdZ4twcbrZvl5bfnh3P3nRXb9abp/K8f)

Returns the zero-based \$n^\text{th}\$  Gobar prime.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 48 bytes

```javascript
for(i=k=j=0;;)j%k%++i?1:~i?i=++k-(j|=k):print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPTNts2y9bA2lozSzVbVVs7097Qqi7TPtNWWztbVyOrxjZb06qgKDOvRCNb8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

```ruby
1.step{|n|(2..$.|=n).one?{|x|$.%n%x<1}&&p(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvuCS1oLomr0bDSE9PRa/GNk9TLz8v1b66pqJGRU81T7XCxrBWTa1AI0@z9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 (or 8?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[NbTÂ‡Cp–
```

Outputs with newline delimiter.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2i8p5HDTo4aFzgWPGib//w8A)

If outputting as an infinite list is allowed it could be 1 byte less:

```
∞ʒbTÂ‡Cp
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5OSQg43PWpY6Fzw/z8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
[          # Start an infinite loop:
 N         #  Push the 0-based loop-index
  b        #  Convert it to a binary string
   T       #  Push 10
    Â      #  Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
     ‡     #  Transliterate the 1s to 0s and vice versa in the binary string
      C    #  Convert it back from a binary string to an integer
       p   #  Check if this integer is a prime number
        –  #  If it is: Print the loop-index `N` with trailing newline

∞          # Push an infinite positive list
 ʒ         # Filter it by:
  bTÂ‡Cp   #  Same as above
           # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

`bTÂ‡C` could alternatively be `2в_2β` for the same byte-count in both programs: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5OMLmyKNzq3qeD/fwA).

```python
  2в       #  Convert the integer to a base-2 list
    _      #  Check for each if it's equal to 0: 1 if 0; 0 otherwise
     2β    #  Convert it from a base-2 list back to an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
BCḄẒƲ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/J@eGOloe7Jh3bpPz/vykA)

Takes an input `n` from STDIN and outputs the first `n` Gobar numbers. If we have to output all Gobar numbers, the following works for 9 bytes

```
ṄBCḄẒƲ¡‘ß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//4bmEQkPhuIThupLGssKh4oCYw5///w)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
òî_â┌ä¶╛p∟
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7LDrl/DouKUjMOkwrbilZtw4oif//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
ò        ∟  # Do while true without popping,
ò           # using the following eight characters as inner code-block:
 î          #  Push the 1-based loop-index
  _         #  Duplicate it
   â        #  Pop and convert it to a binary-list
    ┌       #  Invert each boolean
     ä      #  Convert it from a binary-list back to an integer
      ¶     #  Check if it's a prime number
       ╛    #  If it is:
        p   #   Pop and print the 1-based loop-index with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>81</s> 73 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*.

```r
while(T<-T+1)(k=(p=2^(0:log2(T)))%*%!T%/%p%%2)<2|sum(!k%%1:k)>2||print(T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUFMj21ajwNYoTsPAKic/3UgjRFNTU1VLVTFEVV@1QFXVSNPGqKa4NFdDMVtV1dAqW9POqKamoCgzrwSo8v9/AA)

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbULO6wNYoTsPAKic/3UgjRFOTK9u2QFVLVTFEVV@1QFXViCvbxqimuDRXQzFbVdXQKlvTzqimpqAoM68EqLr2/38A)

Comment: in-lining the declarations for `p` and `k` gives [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUFMj21ajwNYoTsPAKic/3UgjRFNTU1VLVTFEVV@1QFXVSNPGqKa4NFdDMVtV1dAqW9POqKamoCgzrwSo8v9/AA) by removing those pesky `{}`!

Comment: @Giuseppe, nice golfs, thanks! I don't know how I missed the dot product trick...

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
λb†Bæ;ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BBb%E2%80%A0B%C3%A6%3B%C8%AF&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Takes a number n and returns the first n numbers.

```
λ    ;ȯ # First n numbers where...
 b      # Binary
  †     # Vectorised logical not (Vyxal uses 1/0 for booleans)
   B    # When converted back to a number
    æ   # Is prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>77</strike>, <strike>70</strike>(@ovs), <strike>65</strike>, 64 bytes

```python
*p,x,z,P=5*[1]
while[p[z^x]or print(x)]:P*=x;x+=1;p+=-~P%x,;z|=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X6tAp0KnSifA1lQr2jCWqzwjMyc1uiC6Kq4iNr9IoaAoM69Eo0Iz1ipAy7bCukLb1tC6QNtWty5AtULHuqrGtuL/fwA)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X6tAp0KnSifA1lQr2jCWqzwjMydVocKqQtvW0LpA21a3LkC1Qse6qsa2wroguiquIja/SKGgKDOvRKNC0zpAy7bi/38A)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQvaeYTVC6knbJ3MG9GAQFCmFDCP2ku9t78tZ0lbl3z@DGVgmHqJ6Uz4OwiGE/QAdE1z6GaysoFxLayk5y51JHTM5rhoaDYdv7Dw)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0qnQkerwNZQx4irPCMzJ1WhwqpA2zYxJ0ejQrVSIS2/SKFSITNPoUBTK7oi1rqqxrbCuiquAiykkJiXolBQlJlXolGhaV2hbWv4/z8A)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using [Wilson's theorem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/64121) for the primality test: [TIO](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQvaeYTVC6knbJ3MG9GAQFCmFDCP2ku9t78tZ0lbl3z@DGVgmHqJ6Uz4OwiGE/QAdE1z6GaysoFxLayk5y51JHTM5rhoaDYdv7Dw)

Comment: Thanks, @ovs. Neat trick. I managed to squeeze out another 5 bytes on top of that by losing the square and changing the prime store to (inverted) indicator list.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 75 bytes

Prints the sequence "forever" (i.e. until call stack overflow).

```javascript
for(k=0;f=d=>x%--d?f(d):x>1&d<2;)f(x=++k^~-(1<<32-Math.clz32(k)))&&print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPb1sA6zTbF1q5CVVc3xT5NI0XTqsLOUC3FxshaM02jwlZbOzuuTlfD0MbG2EjXN7EkQy85p8rYSCNbU1NTTa2gKDOvBMj@/x8A)

Or  **<s>77</s>  76 bytes** without `Math.clz32()`:

```javascript
for(k=0;f=d=>x%--d?f(d):x>1&d<2;)f(x=++k^(g=k=>k&&1|2*g(k>>1))(k))&&print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbBCkBAEADQrzHN0JZ1Emb8iZJtxRRa2vbg35d3evsc53sJ2/WY2Obsz4DKde/ZsaTCGDd6dNQlseCGpiePiatKJ1xZWRTAvk25oopYIlQigCtsx/M35w8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
for(i=1,oo,if(isprime(2^#binary(i)-i-1),print(i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1lAnP18nM00js7igKDM3VcMoTjkpMy@xqFIjU1M3U9dQUwconlcC5Glq/v8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹ηＷ‹ⅉθ«≦⊕η≔↨Ｅ↨η²¬κ²ζ¿∧‹¹ζ⬤…²ζ﹪ζκ⟦Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xD4IwEIVn@BU3XpM6wOqETiRCjJsxDhUqJZYW2qIJxt9eS8p279337l0jmGk0k96XapxdPQ8PbnAi@7Swtu8UZhREUB/RSw544tbiFQmFiRD4pknFxg0sVWP4wJXjbYwk2@LALMfAxUFQyEO81g5fhESxrHT/BCxUGyuy1aRQSIkXpjqOeTQq3c5S40IhhMMHZ9Mrh7cjsw4FuYc7P@@z3O/e8g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` Gobar primes. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start at `1` (arbitrary, just has to be between `0` and `3` inclusive).

```
Ｗ‹ⅉθ«
```

Repeat until `n` Gobar primes have been printed.

```
≦⊕η
```

Try the next integer.

```
≔↨Ｅ↨η²¬κ²ζ
```

Convert it to base `2`, flip the bits, then convert back.

```
¿∧‹¹ζ⬤…²ζ﹪ζκ
```

If the result is at least `2` and has no nontrivial proper factors, then...

```
⟦Ｉη
```

Print the Gobar prime on its own line.

The above algorithm appears to be O(n²) in complexity, taking 20 seconds to calculate the first 1400 Gobar primes and probably 20 minutes to calculate the first 7708. I've implemented a faster algorithm for <s>66</s> 56 bytes that can calculate the first 7708 Gobar primes in <s>20</s> seconds (although it does start to slow down after that point due to using a memory-inefficient method of generating primes):

```
Ｎθ≔²η≔υζＷ‹Ｌυθ«≔Φζ‹×κκ⊗ηε≔⁺Φ⮌…η⊗η⬤ε﹪κμζζ≦⊗η≔⁺υ⁻⊖⊗ηζυ»Ｉ…υθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NasMwEITP8VPouAIVSi4p5BQSCoU6hNAXUJzFEllLjn5S6tJnV9eJQ38ug0bMfLvbGB0ar6mUF9fntM3dAQOc5bJaxWhbB3MlzI/LSgzs3o0lFPCKMbK4NhnIUomzlOKzmk3ZZ0uJWYMS19yb7TDCSYkTJzc@HwiPYKRkh4y8t3aU4726xwuGiLDXrkUw/2srIkAlan/M5Edyd/0e5G3JWa37CTr1bqf8mcQH1dbxY4NNwA5dYvyvMSOKJXPvq9oF6xKsdWT5aAjXxvcjge@Wy1IWi8en8nChbw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` Gobar primes, although it actually works by calculating the primes up to the next power of 2. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔²η≔υζ
```

Start with the primes up to (but not including) 2, i.e. no primes at all.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυθ«
```

Repeat until enough Gobar primes have been obtained.

```
≔Φζ‹×κκ⊗ηε
```

Get the primes up to the square root of the next power of 2.

```
≔⁺Φ⮌…η⊗η⬤ε﹪κμζζ
```

Calculate all the primes between the current and next power of 2 by trial division by all of those primes. (Sieving them would probably be even faster.)

```
≦⊗η
```

Double the current power of 2.

```
≔⁺υ⁻⊖⊗ηζυ
```

Complement the bits in all of the primes up to the current power of 2 with respect to that number of bits e.g. primes up to 4 have three bits complemented resulting in `4, 5` while primes up to 128 would have eight bits complemented. (Note that the list of primes is in reverse order so the complements are in ascending order as desired.)

```
»Ｉ…υθ
```

Output the first `n` Gobar primes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 106 bytes

```python
n=1
while 1:(k:=int(bin((n^~-2**~-len(bin(n))))[3:],2))>1and all(k%m for m in range(2,k))and print(n);n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwFAX3nuJvhP9ru0i6kUi8iChEjDYkfQ2hIG569dh2ljMw@TcPE/pzLrXCqsN3CMmTMhyNDZj5GcCMx9Lpplm65LEbyMqtN/dWi1yVw4tcShyPI72nQiMFUHH4eNZtFNl6LtsOcsHJqlr/)

Infinite output

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```ruby
require'prime'
1.step{|n|n.to_s(2).tr('01','10').to_i(2).prime?&&p(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU8xDoMwENv7CqYGpAjljiSEqU@pVImBoZQGGKrSt6c2g@9s30W@5P3xKSWP733Ko1ny9BzNRdp1G5fvMR9zu73ua61Nu@XaODHWiDMN3Ynu@eB2vS713PxK8bYKtkq2Egco0AHQCq2YagSoB1t1mHfwPGaeHbMAHuAHcuxF6CgAdITusZfgJXZ4A/jAfmZ6FrIzXigl8pDzGp7DG0QDC/c8PeaKp2SyBK4wWxgqPb2eLJExWBKnAxmz1SkLfyX6Bw)

- Saved 1 thanks to @ovs

Full program, prints the sequence indefinitely on new lines.

```
1.step{|n|     # each n>0
n.to_s(2)      # convert to binary string  
.tr('01','10') # swap '01'
.to_i(2)       # reconvert to int
.prime?&&p(n)  # put n if prime
```

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##HU8xDoMwENv7CqYGpAjljiSEqU@pVImBoZQGGKrSt6c2g@9s30W@5P3xKSWP733Ko1ny9BzNRdp1G5fvMR9zu73ua61Nu@XaODHWiDMN3Ynu@eB2vS713PxK8bYKtkq2Egco0AHQCq2YagSoB1t1mHfwPGaeHbMAHuAHcuxF6CgAdITusZfgJXZ4A/jAfmZ6FrIzXigl8pDzGp7DG0QDC/c8PeaKp2SyBK4wWxgqPb2eLJExWBKnAxmz1SkLfyX6Bw) with `&&` instead of `if`.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFW9oCgzN1Wdy1CvuCS1oLomr0YjL05Fr8Y2T1MPLGWvplagkadZ@/8/AA) is a much shorter way to reverse the bits.

Comment: Actually, it seems [shorter](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvuCS1oLomr0bDSE@vzDYvTkWvxjZPUy8/L9W@uqaipky1wsawVk2tQCNPs/b/fwA) to do the primality test by hand.

Comment: @dingledooper wow that's a lot of improvements! Shouldn't you post your answer? It is not a completely different approach but still much different than mine

Comment: I sort of didn't want to post another one, but [sure why not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236595/88546)?