# Find prime gaps

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, number-theory

A [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) is the difference between two consecutive primes. More specifically, if *p* and *q* are primes with *p* <*q* and *p*+1, *p*+2, ..., _q_−1 are not primes, the primes *p* and *q* define a gap of *n* = *q_−_p*. The gap is said to be **started** by *p*, and to have **length** *n*.

It is known that arbitrarily large prime gaps exist. That is, given *n* there exists a prime gap of length *n* or larger. However, a prime gap of length exactly *n* may not exist (but a larger one will).

## The challenge

Given a positive integer `n`, output the first prime that starts a gap of length `n` or larger.

As an example, for input `4` the output should be `7`, because 7 and 11 are the first consecutive primes that differ by at least 4 (the previous gaps are 1, from 2 to 3; 2, from 3 to 5; and 2, from 5 to 7). For input `3` the answer should also be `7` (there are no gaps of length 3).

## Additional rules

- The algorithm should theoretically work for arbitrarily high `n`. In practice, it is acceptable if the program is limited by time, memory or data-type size.
- Input and output can be taken by any [reasonable means](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

```
Input -> Output

1        2
2        3
3        7
4        7
6        23
10       113
16       523
17       523
18       523
30       1327
50       19609
100      370261
200      20831323
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23844/36398)

Comment: By p-q you mean q-p right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes; corrected, thanks!

Comment: [OEIS A104138](https://oeis.org/A104138)

Comment: [OEIS A002386](https://oeis.org/A002386) (Related)

Comment: Gaps of most odd lengths will not exist.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes, all gaps except the first are even, because all primes except the first (`2`) are odd, so they are separated by even lengths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
zṅọ⊃∆ṇ
```

This is *extremely* inefficient (the `16` test case took over an hour to compute on my machine).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/v@rhztaHu3sfdTU/6mh7uLP9/39DAwA)

#### Explanation

The sequence seems to have the property that **a(n) <= 2^n**.

```
z       Push 2^input.
 ṅ      Get the first 2^input prime numbers.
  ọ     Get the deltas of the list.
   ⊃∆   Find the index of the first that is greater than or equal to the input.
     ṇ  Push the index-th prime number.
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10, 9, 8</s> 10 bytes

```
Æn_$:ð1#»2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW168itXhDYbKh3Yb/f//3wwA)

Two bytes saved thanks to @Dennis! (and then added back again due to edge-cases)

Explanation:

```
Æn          #   The next prime after 'P'
  _$        #   Minus 'P'
    :       #   Divided by 'N'
            #
            # This will give a falsy value unless the distance to the next prime is >= N
            #
     ð      # Treat all of that as a single dyad (fucntion with two arguments). 
            # We'll call it D(P, N)
            #
      1#    # Find the first 'P' where D(P, input()) is truthy
        »2  # Return the maximum of that result and 2
```

Comment: Do we know for certain that the result will always be greater-than-or-equal-to the input? (`#` will count up from the input here) It seems reasonable to assume this but I for one have no idea if it's a valid assumption. EDIT: FYI to fix (if necessary) prefix with `2ð`

Comment: @JonathanAllan [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) implies that a prime's gap is strictly less than the prime itself.

Comment: @Dennis brilliant thank you very much! TMYK...

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
2//.x_ /;NextPrime@x-x<#:>x+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfSF9fryJeQd/aL7WiJKAoMzfVoUK3wkbZyq5C21DtP1Akr0TBIS3a0CD2PwA)

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
(t=2;While[NextPrime@t-t<#,t++];t)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo8TWyDo8IzMnNdovtaIkoCgzN9WhRLfERlmnRFs71rpEU@0/UDCvRMEhLdrYIPY/AA)

## Mathematica, 77 bytes

```
Prime@Min@Position[s=Differences@Prime@Range[(r=#)^3+1],#&@@Select[s,#>=r&]]&
```

Comment: Clever clever... you don't even need to make sure both `p` and `q` are prime... The first code seems invalid, though, because it only goes up to 65535 unless you explicitly feed the argument `MaxIterations`.

Comment: Also, -2 bytes for the 35-byte version: `(For[t=2,NextPrime@t-t<#,t++];t)&`

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>106 102 93 77 73</s> 72 bytes

This generates an infinite list of primes first, then looks for the prime gaps. The prime list was taken from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners). It can probably be shortened, but I haven't figured out how yet:)

Thanks to @BruceForte for -4 bytes and @Zgrab for -1 byte!

```hs
f n=[x|(y,x)<-zip=<<tail$[n|n<-[2..],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]],y-x>=n]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCsMgFADQq/xABgUV7ay5iDj8QVupfkQdkpK7W7I@3gfHN5ayVgJy/rzZJU5u5S83Z@3EXHZPN1npX0oFgaUwdmiueqxA/EGSJgRxyfNwFLZNr4qZwEHrmSbsULFBAm@UMjqAlJByHxOMfkaNb2xj/QE)

Comment: Of course there is some monad magic, thanks :)

Comment: `zip=<<tail$[...]` saves a byte.

Comment: "This generates an **infinite** list of primes first, then ..." : well, then should never happen ? (ie, it will only happen after an infinitely long time, the time to "first generate" procedurally an infinite list of primes)

Comment: Haskell uses lazy evaluation, so only as many entries of that list are generated as are actually used. So those primes are generated up to the point where we actually find the points. If you try it you'll see that for any `n` it will stop after a finite amount of time :) (Haskell is not a procedural, but a functional language with lazy evaluation.)

Comment: PS: I highly recommend learning Haskell, as it has a lot of concepts that are just no applicable in the more (up to known) widely known procedural or imperative languages!

Comment: @flawr: I guessed it was something like it (like pipelining in unix), but I was "tongue-in-cheek"ly pointing out that the wording "generate ... first, then" is not 100% correct ^^ just change "then" to "while it" ? )

Comment: Well it is an infinite list, by definition it does not have an end. What I described is just what is happening under the hood in the usual interpreters, but that is not specified as part of the language so you cannot tell that!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 14 bytes

It filters from [1, inf), filtering by primality(`P_`) and that the next prime filtered from (n, inf), has a different >= to the input.

```
f&P_T<tQ-fP_Yh
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%26P_T%3CtQ-fP_Yh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A6%0A10%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A30&debug=0).

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>97</s> <s>96</s> 91 bytes

```powershell
param($n)for($a=$b=2){for(;'1'*++$b-match'^(?!(..+)\1+$)..'){if($b-$a-ge$n){$a;exit}$a=$b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPMy2/SEMl0VYlydZIsxrEsVY3VNfS1lZJ0s1NLEnOUI/TsFfU0NPT1owx1FbR1NNT16zOTNMASqsk6qanAk2oVkm0Tq3ILKkFG1Nb@///f2MDAA)

Takes input `$n`, sets `$a` and `$b` equal to `2`, then enters an infinite `for` loop. Inside, we loop up on `$b` until we [get to the next prime](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57636/42963). Then we check if `$b-$a` (i.e., the gap) is `-g`reaterthanor`e`qual to `$n`. If it is, we output `$a` and `exit`. Otherwise we set `$a` to be `$b` and increment `$b` and start our next search.

Warning: This is *slow* for large input. In fact, it can't complete the `50` or higher tests within the 60s timeout on TIO. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
´ȯ!V≥⁰Ẋ-İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9odXNr///CtMivIVbiiaXigbDhuootxLBw////MTA)

```
´       İp  -- with the primes
 ȯ!         -- get the value at position
      Ẋ-    -- where the difference of the current and next prime
   V≥⁰      -- is greater or equal than the input N
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
(For[i=2;p=NextPrime,i+#>p@i,i=p@i];i)&
(* or *)
(For[i=1;p=Prime,p@i+++#>p@i,];p[i-1])&
```

#### 33 byte version (not valid because it only goes up to the 65535th prime)

```
p=NextPrime;2//.i_/;p@i-i<#:>p@i&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>96</s> 88 bytes

***- 8 bytes Thanks to @Maltysen***

```python
n,p,r=input(),3,[2]
while p-r[-1]<n:r+=[p]*all(p%i for i in range(2,p));p+=1
print r[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1BCsIwEAXQfU8xG0lrU2hSW6Wak4QsSo02EKZDqKinj6O4eIvP8P/Qe1tW1Hler94IITJKkskEpMdWVrKTVrviuYTogZpkG@UuOKbaWHL7KcaSdgFua4IAASFNePelllRVZ6qNKigF3OBXyzz@H1Kjf/kZvi@zAig069iBDUy1bGBHduIb5779AA)

Comment: saved a bunch of bytes: https://repl.it/JwBe

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 63 bytes

```
->\d{(grep &is-prime,^∞).rotor(2=>-1).first({-d>=[-] $_})[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf1y4mpVojvSi1QEEts1i3oCgzN1Un7lHHPE29ovyS/CINI1s7XUNNvbTMouISjWrdFDvbaN1YBZX4Ws1og9ja/9YKxYmVCkoq8Qq2dgrVaSAJJYW0/CIFQz09IwPr/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## R + gmp, 55 bytes

Makes use of the nextprime function from the gmp library

```
s=2;n=scan();while((x=gmp::nextprime(s))-s<n)s=x;cat(s)
```

Comment: You need to add `cat(s)` at the end. Implicit printing doesn't work in full programs.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
gNestWhile[p=NextPrime,2,p@#-#<g&]
```

`Function` with first argument `g`. Starting with `2`, applies the function `p=NextPrime` repeatedly as long as `p@#-#<g&` gives `True` (the gap between the current prime and the next prime is less than `g`).

Answer (score 2):

### C = <s>141</s> 109 bytes ; C++, D = 141 bytes ; C#, Java = 143 bytes

**WARNING** : LOW PERFORMANCE ALGORITHM

This code was not able to calculate the prime gap for `g(200)` within 10 minutes. For `g(100)`, it needed 10 seconds ( C++ version )

C++ and D version :

```cpp
int p(int d){for(int i=2;i<=d/2;++i){if(!(d%i))return 0;}return 1;}int g(int d){int f=2,n=3;while(n-f<d){f=n;do{++n;}while(!p(n));}return f;}
```

C# and Java version :

```
int p(int d){for(int i=2;i<=d/2;++i){if(d%i==0)return 0;}return 1;}int g(int d){int f=2,n=3;while(n-f<d){f=n;do{++n;}while(p(n)==0);}return f;}
```

C version, -32 bytes thanks to ceilingcat  :

```
i;p(d){for(i=2;d/2/i;)if(!(d%i++))return 0;return 1;}f;n;g(d){for(f=2,n=3;n-f<d;)for(f=n;!p(++n););return f;}
```

Differences between the C#/Java and C/C++/D version : `!p(n)` <==> `p(n)==0`

Comment: Can reverse `return 0; return 1` and remove the `!` before `p(++n)`

Comment: `d%i==0` and `!(d%i)` can be `d%i<0`. Also, using D's template system the solution in D can be: `T p(T)(T d){for(T i=2;i<=d/2;++i)if(d%i<1)return 0;return 1;}T g(T)(T d){T f=2,n=3;while(n-f<d){f=n;do++n;while(!p(n));}return f;`. (The removal of braces after the `for` and the `do` might apply to C++ as well)

Comment: I posted the separate D version, which utilizes D specific tricks that can't be found in C/C++/C#/Java.

Comment: `int p(int d){for(int i=2;i<=d/2;++i)if(!(d%i))return 0;return 1;}int g(int d){int f=2,n=3;while(n-f<d){f=n;do++n;while(!p(n));}return f;}` <- that should work for the C++ version

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
->g{*r,f=2,3;f+=1while r.find{|n|f%n<1}||r<<f&&g>f-z=r[-2];z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoMgFADQX/FlsZVKNnpK@xHxYbHdCpbEhdDy@u12Dh7TWYIpYpxTjRxMx98DNEaFZf3/GEpY/TeRJ3h4rTIRag1VNY8gLoNWdG64cnkqKfv2JbfPnijSzmzkLNjoXC43)

Answer (score 2):

## D, <s>127</s> <s>125</s> 122 bytes

WARNING: LOW PERFORMANCE ALGORITHM!!

```d
T p(T)(T d){T r;for(T i=2;i<=d/2;)r=d%i++<1||r;return r;}T g(T)(T d){T f=2,n=3;while(n-f<d){f=n;while(p(++n)){}}return f;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsMgEARr8wqaSJxIHIWUZ37BByJhnJMcsC4kLmzeTihcpNhiR7Pra3VyUQ6Ukx42JxlD4lbIGqTB@qtBYOtPpPVw23dGHvOHY/OKk9PfMFhzjvaO65PmUcVLGBoONh5gUVpHgK2U4yBgEd9EXr4eFBXITYqOXkviLN/Z9y2UUHQrUx7nqJSBfgIUpdYf)

## How?

HatsuPointerKun again, but I'll do the D specific sorcery.

- Template system can infer types `T p(T)(T d)`, and is shorter than C++
- `r=d%i++<1||r`, D specific shenanigans, might work in C/C++, but I don't know.
- `p(++n)`, same as above, not sure if it works in C/C++
- `while(p(++n)){}`, here one sees why D is bad at golfing, one can't use `;` as an empty statement.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```perl6
{+(1...(^$_+*)>>.is-prime eqv!<<^$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlvDUE9PTyNOJV5bS9POTi@zWLegKDM3VSG1sEzRxgYorln7vzixUiFNA8hUSMsvUjDUMdIx1jHRMdMxNNAxBJLmOoYWOsYG/wE)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                   }  # Block taking n as $_
   1...   # Sequence 1,2,... until
       (^$_+*)  # Range [i,i+n)
              >>.is-prime  # is-prime for each
                          eqv!<<^$_  # Equals (True,False,False,False,...)?
 +(                                )  # Length of sequence
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
f n=until(\p->and[any((<1).mod k)[2..k-1]|k<-[p+1..p+n-1]])(+1)2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBDsIgEADAr@wRghAXTU@tH6EcSCtKoOvGtgcT3y6Kl0nmHtZ8LaXWCDTstKUiRtaXQLML9BKiR2mWxwxZOmtM1ujfudeOFRrDin73UiiUti4hEQzAz0QbuAh4gAi2cWqcG10Dj387Xz9TLOG2Vj0xfwE)

Count up from `2` looking for a `p` such that `[p+1..p+n-1]` are all composite.

`p` itself will always be prime: otherwise `[p..p+n-1]` is a larger prime gap and we'd have returned `p-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 28 bytes

```
{~µs||~s-r>=:|_Xr\r=s]]s=s+1
```

### Explanation

```
{         DO
~µs||     IF s is prime THEN (note, s starts as 3)
~s-r>=:   IF the gap between s (current prime) and r (prev prime) is big enough
|_Xr      THEN QUIT, printing prev prime r
\r=s      ELSE (gap too small, but s is prime), set r to prime s
]]        END IF x2, leaving us in the WHILE
s=s+1     increment s, retest for primality ...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞<ØD¥I@Ïн
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8m8MzXA4t9XQ43H9h7///pgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/f9HHfNsDs9wObS00uFw/4W9/3X@RxvqGOkY65jomOkYGugYAklzHUMLHWMDHVODWAA). (Test Suite doesn't contain the last two test cases, because TIO times out for those.)

Since [the other question is closed as a dupe of this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179017/52210), I'm posting [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179027/52210) here as well.

**Explanation:**

```python
∞           # Get an infinite list in the range [1, ...]
 <          # Decrease it by one to make it in the range [0, ...]
  Ø         # Get for each the (0-indexed) n'th prime: [2,3,5,7,11,...]
   D        # Duplicate this list of primes
    ¥       # Get all deltas (difference between each pair): [1,2,2,4,2,...]
     I@     # Check for each if they are larger than or equal to the input
            #  i.e. 4 → [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,...]
       Ï    # Only keep the truthy values of the prime-list
            #  → [23,31,47,53,61,...]
        н   # And keep only the first item (which is output implicitly)
            #  → 23
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>99</s> 92 bytes

```java
n->{int a=2,b=3,f,k;for(;b-a<n;)for(f=0,a=b;f<2;)for(f=++b,k=2;k<f;)f=f%k++<1?0:f;return a;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NVBLboMwFNznFE@RIoH8QDY0H8U4PUGzyTLKwhBcORATgUlVIbY9QI/Yi1A7TTejN6OnmdFc5F1Gl3M1FbXsOniT2gwzAG1s2SpZlLD39CFAEXg0IXfKOHPQWWl1AXswIGAy0W7wD1IkmIsUFVZcNW3A80hmhof@VoKiFDlXWfIvEJJjJRJeZcpJQi0qQjL2SreKt6XtWwOSjxP3ebc@r13eM/be6DNcXeHgYFtt3o8nkOFfW@/sq2jYgik/fPvjaWCYYIovuMQVrnGDjCJbIVsj22BKcekopWP4cAA4fHa2vMZNb@Obs7e1CTSZw8/XN8yJid0Y4XOJcfoF) (Largest test case is excluded, because it times out in TIO.)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{               // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int a=2,b=3,     //  Prime-pair `a,b`, starting at 2,3
      f,           //  Prime-checker flag `f`, starting uninitialized
      k;           //  Temp integer, starting uninitialized
  for(;b-a         //  Loop as long as the difference between the current pair of primes
          <n;)     //  is smaller than the input
    for(f=0,       //   (Re)set the prime-checker flag to 0
        a=b;       //   Replace `a` with `b`, since we're about to search for the next prime-pair
        f<2;)      //   Inner loop as long as the prime-checker flag is still 0 (or 1)
                   //   (which means the new `b` is not a prime)
      for(f=++b,   //    Increase `b` by 1 first, and set this value to the prime-checker flag
          k=2;     //    Set `k` to 2
          k<f;)    //    Inner loop as long as `k` is still smaller than the prime-checker flag
        f=         //     Change the prime-checker flag to:
          f%k++<1? //      If the prime-checker flag is divisible by `k`
           0       //       Set the prime-checker flag to 0
          :        //      Else:
           f;      //       Leave it unchanged
                   //    (If any integer `k` in the range [2, `b`) can evenly divide `b`,
                   //     the prime-checker flag becomes 0 and the loop stops)
  return a;}       //  And finally after all the nested loops, return `a` as result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 33 bytes

```
{x:({v:⊟v<=-x}↦primes+2)@0@0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lMqfyfpmBl@7@6wkqjuszqUdf8Mhtb3YraR23LCooyc1OLtY00HQwcDGr/lyQD1SkkaxjqGOkY65jomOkYGugYAklzHUMLHWMDHVMg18BAk4urWgGolEsBCMqLMktSc/I0kvWUFHR17RSU9NI0kjU1uWoV8vMUSpL/AwA)

Or, 28 chars/34 bytes: `{x:({v:⊟v≤-x}↦primes+2)@0@0}`

I'll explain this using an equivvalent, ASCII equivalent:

```
{x:({v:(-)over v<=-x}from primes+2)@0@0}
{x:                                    }    lambda w/ parameter `x`
                          primes+2          overlapping pairs of primes
                                            [[2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 7], ...]
    {v:             }from                   select prime pairs `v = [a, b]`...
       (-)over v                            ...where `a` - `b`...
                <=-x                        is <= `x`
   (                              )@0@0     select the first element of the first pair
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 36 char, 72 bytes

```
∇r←h w;k
r←2
→0×⍳w≤r-⍨k←1πr⋄r←k⋄→2
∇
```

1π is the function "next prime"; test:

```
  h¨1 2 3 4 6 10 16 17 18 30 50 100 200
2 3 7 7 23 113 523 523 523 1327 19609 370261 20831323
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@§XnÈj}aX+j}a2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QKdYbshqfWFYK2p9YTI&input=OA) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QKdYbshqfWFYK2p9YTI&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNiAxMCAxNiAxNyAxOCAzMCA1MCAxMDBdLW0) (except `200` - seriously, don't even try it! If you want to verify that `200` returns the correct result, you can increase the starting value of `2` at the end to something closer to the expected output.)

```
@§XnÈj}aX+j}a2     :Implicit input of integer U
@                  :Function taking an integer X as argument
 §                 :  Is U <= ...
  Xn               :  Subtract X from
    È              :    Function taking an integer as input
     j             :      Is prime?
      }            :    End function
       a           :    Get the first integer that returns true when passed through that function starting at
        X+j        :      X plus is X prime
           }       :End function
            a2     :Get the first integer that returns true when passed through that function starting at 2
```