# Number of bits needed to represent the product of the first primes

Tags: code-golf, primes

## Input

An integer \$n\$ greater than or equal to 1.

## Output

The number of bits in the binary representation of the integer that is the product of the first \$n\$ primes.

## Example

The product of the first two primes is 6. This needs 3 bits to represent it.

Given unlimited memory and time your code should always output the correct value for `n <= 1000000`.

Comment: That would be [A045716](https://oeis.org/A045716) :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Except that the first term is different (must be 2 here instead of 1).

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a dupe of [sum of first n primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170110/78410) (which was the closest to "calculate first n primes" I could find) and [bit length of n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104785/78410), since the two are the necessary building blocks and there is no way to avoid them.

Comment: @Bubbler: The bit-length Q&A is "for any positive 32-bit integer".  This question requires BigInt.  It's only a duplicate if you limit this question to languages where the native integer type is a BigInt, or where one works as a drop-in replacement including for bit-scan functions.  A machine-code answer to that question is trivial (4 bytes for x86, for a `bsr` bit-scan reverse + `ret`), but would take much more work for this question.  (You could approximate the answer by summing bit-lengths (logs) of each prime, but low bits can make the difference between carry-out to a new bit-pos.)

Comment: @Bubbler If you look, for example, at dingledooper's answer you'll find at least one nontrivial synergy that is unique to the  combined  task: Using the primorial instead of the more common (squared) factorial to generate the prime numbers.

Comment: To be pedantic, you should specify "bits of the binary representation". I could compactly represent the 3rd primorial with just `3#` or as a factorization binary string `111` (where each base is the prime power). In some number theory programming problems those are useful.

Answer (score 8):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 24 bytes

```
[ primorial bit-length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWgxhp4GlMxNzoPykzJLyzOJUheLUwtLUvGSgsoKi1JKSyoKizLwSBWsuLiMDhWhDnaTY/9FAmcxcsF4FoC7dnNS89JIMhdj/uYkFCnr/AQ)

```
primorial  ! get the primorial of the input
bit-length ! how many bits does it have?
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES12), 75 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Expects a BigInt.

```javascript
n=>eval("for(p=k=1n;p;d?0:p*=n--&&k)for(d=k++;k%d--;)p.toString(2).length")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoMgEEX3PQUx1jAlGOuydNpD9AISQWshA1Hixnh2qqv/kvfyf3rVSz9PMUkKxuYBM@HLrtrzYggzj@jwTioq824e8YYkZVU5OJVBJ4RyVyOlglin8EnzRCNvofaWxvQtIJ@dt4kRQ3bcHPtE1jYnCQFsuzDWB1qCt7UPI@80Lzfa4ajLbeAEewfqsuc/)

---

## JavaScript (ES12), 76 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(p=k=1n;n;d?0:p*=n--&&k)for(d=k++;k%d--;);p.toString(2).length")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoMgEADvvoIYa9gSjHos3fYR/YBE0VrIQpR4Mb6d6mkmmfnpTa/9MocoyQ8mjZgIX2bTjuejX3hAiw0pUsO7foQ7kpRlaeFKA1ohlL0NUipQoYr@E5eZJt5C5QxN8ZtDukZnIiOGrFEnnsja@hQhgO0ZY72n1TtTOT/xTvNipwPOt9hHTnB0oLIj/QE)

#### Commented

This is a version without `eval()` for readability.

```javascript
n => {                 // n = input
  for(                 // outer loop:
    p =                //   p = product
    k = 1n;            //   k = current prime candidate
    n;                 //   stop when n = 0
    d ?                //   if d is not 0:
      0                //     do nothing
    :                  //   else:
      p *= n-- && k    //     decrement n and multiply p by k
  )                    //
    for(               //   inner loop:
      d = k++;         //     start with d = k and increment k
      k % d--;         //     decrement d until it divides k
    );                 //
  return p.toString(2) // convert the final product to base 2
         .length       // and return the length
}                      //
```

Comment: I naively thought that you had to use bigint for big ints in JavaScript!

Comment: @Simd but `1n` *is* a bigint...

Comment: @Neil Ah, thanks.

Comment: `n=>eval("for(p=k=1n;p;d?0:p*=n--&&k)for(d=k++;k%d--;)p.toString(2).length")` with input changed to bigint.

Comment: For those wondering why not to do a tagged template ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)) (i.e. n=>eval\`...\`) is because "If the argument of `eval()` is not a string, `eval()` returns the argument unchanged." ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#:~:text=If%20the%20argument%20of%20eval()%20is%20not%20a%20string%2C%20eval()%20returns%20the%20argument%20unchanged.)) and a tagged template literal passes in an Array as the first argument (not a string primitive)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
Ẓ#PBL
```

A full program that accepts an integer from STDIN that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrknKAU4@//@bAgA)**

#### How?

Straight forward, just saving a byte over the monadic Link `ÆN€PBL`

```
Ẓ#PBL - Main Link: no arguments
 #    - starting at {implict k=0} find the first {STDIN} k for which:
Ẓ     -   is prime?
  P   - product
   B  - to binary
    L - length
```

Comment: Pretty fast too!

Comment: Uses `sympy` under the hood. Will get slower as the input increases as it is testing every single integer for primality. I don't really understand why `ÆN€PBL` is so much slower for small inputs, I would have thought calling `lambda z: sympy.ntheory.generate.prime(z)` for `[1..input]` would be as fast or faster than repeating `lambda z: int(sympy.primetest.isprime(z))` for each number until `input` primes are found. Perhaps it's not using the same hardcoded lookup for small primes.

Comment: `Ẓ#` is a clever replacement for `ÆN€`, nice!

Answer (score 6):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 30 bytes

```
n->#binary(vecprod(primes(n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW-_J07ZSTMvMSiyo1ylKTC4ryUzQKijJzU4s18jQ1NSGKbqqk5Rdp5CnYKhjqKBgZ6CgAVeSVAAWUFHTtgEQaktoFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=1,i=1:n and f(n-(b:=x**i%i>0),x*i**b,i+1)or len(bin(x))-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEAXQvaeYjTATp2DqRgLxLgltdKD@htBFPH3U7Vu8@jleO2732sYocUvvvCSC9ujVog@ghIUKY@IcYnfOzva4inZnzmW1i5e90baCs4G7yDSP8hOQgVrCc2WvNHsJJ6rNcDD034mMLw)

The idea is that if `x` is the product of every prime number up to `n`, then the next prime number must not share any prime factors with `x`. This is done by calculating the first `i` greater than `n` such that `x**i%i>0`. This works because if `i` isn't the next prime, all of its prime factors are below `n`, so it will easily divide `x**i`. Raising `x` to the `i`th power makes sure that prime powers are also caught, since `x` by itself only contains each prime factor once.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 34 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.25 bytes

```
ʁǎΠbL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiyoHHjs6gYkwiLCIiLCIyIl0=)

Very simple

### Explained

```
ʁǎΠbL­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ʁǎ     # ‎⁡A list of the first n primes
  Π    # ‎⁢Take the product of that
   bL  # ‎⁣And get the length of the binary representation
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: 357 is the largest input value that works on your TIO link.

Comment: @Simd that's because it times out after 10 seconds (by design). You can use the `T` flag to up the time out to 60 seconds or use the offline interpreter for unlimited time.

Answer (score 4):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 58 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0x:∏select.first:&2..∞=>prime? while->x>0[1+'x/2]]
```

Unfortunately, I have to count bits by counting how many halvings it takes to get to zero since both `log` and `as.binary` no longer work properly once values get into bignum territory. Perhaps there is a smarter way...?

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?2M1JLU)

```
$=>[                ; a function where input is assigned to &
    0               ; push 0 -- we'll use this to count bits later
    x:              ; to x, assign...
    ∏               ; product of
    select.first:&  ; the first <input> number of
    2..∞=>prime?    ; prime numbers in [2..∞]
    while->x>0[     ; while x is greater than zero...
        1+          ; increment our bit count
        'x/2        ; divide x by two in place
    ]               ; end while
]                   ; end function
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 39 bytes

```ruby
->n{'%b'%Prime.take(n).inject(:*)=~/$/}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7OI025ilpSVpuhY31XXt8qrVVZPUVQNAcnolidmpGnmaepl5WanJJRpWWpq2dfoq-rUw5QWlJcUKGoZ6ekYGmnq5iQXVSmkaytXxhrWaCrYKytVp0fGGsbVKUOULFkBoAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

-3 Thanks to alephalpha:

```
n->#binary(lcm(primes(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifaPs/T9dOOSkzL7GoUiMnOVejoCgzN7VYI09TU/N/Wn6RRp6toY6CoYGOAlAir0QjESIDAA)

#### [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes (original)

```
n->logint(lcm(primes(n)),2)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifaPs/T9cuJz89M69EIyc5V6OgKDM3tVgjT1NTx0hT2/B/Wn6RRp6toY6CoYGOAlASqCwRJKv5HwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATLAB](https://nl.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 35 bytes

*upd. use `nthprime` instead of `primes(n)`(get all primes up to n)*

```matlab
@(n)ceil(log2(prod(nthprime(1:n))))
```

Full code with test cases:

```matlab
f=...
@(n)ceil(log2(prod(nthprime(1:n))));
disp(arrayfun(f,1:57));
```

Comment: What's the 300?

Comment: It needs to take arbitrary input, not just the number 300.

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Æppḃ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyU4NnBwJUUxJUI4JTgzJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MiZmbGFncz1M)

##### Explanation

```python
Æppḃ  # Implicit input
Æp    # First n primes
  p   # Product
   ḃ  # To binary
      # Take the length
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅpPbg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGtBQFL6//9GAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ÅpPbg  # Implicit input
Åp     # First n primes
  P    # Product
   b   # To binary
    g  # Take the length
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>98</s> <s>94</s> 92 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to Taylor Alex Raine*

```
=LET(
    a,ROW(1:99),
    LEN(BASE(PRODUCT(TAKE(FILTER(a,MMULT(N(MOD(a,TOROW(a))=0),a^0)=2),A1)),2))
)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Fails for `A1>13`.

Comment: use `1:99` for -2 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Rust + num + num-prime, 59 bytes

```rust
|n|num_prime::nt_funcs::primorial::<num::BigUint>(n).bits()
```

Comment: Does BigUint have a limit to how large an int it can handle?

Comment: @Simd It's arbitrarily large

Comment: How can BigUInt exist and how would it do 0-1?

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
f=:3 :'##:*/p:i.y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WyljBSl1Z2UpLv8AqU69S/X@erZWRgUEFV2pyRr5CmkLefwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｎθ→→Ｗ‹Ｌυθ¿⬤υ﹪ⅈκ⊞υⅈＭ→ＩＬ↨Πυ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8JAEER7f8WWuxALBRtTqZVgJFjZnnHNHW7uzH3En3@egoXYDMw8eNNp5TunJOe9faR4TMOFPY5Uzxo3Ma5Pptfxrz21EQY8cAglbB81JqpgJAJzA9yIYKqgcdckDs9Y0J0Ka1PQb1AWqoElMPx6W29sxJ0K8avdqsDY@mLq4udjWURU57xY5fkkLw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
→→
```

Start searching for primes at `2`.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυθ
```

Stop when `n` primes have been found.

```
¿⬤υ﹪ⅈκ
```

If none of the primes found so far is a factor of the current value, then...

```
⊞υⅈ
```

... push the current value to the list of primes.

```
Ｍ→
```

Otherwise increment the current value. (Note that after a prime is pushed, the value is not immediately incremented, but if more primes are needed then it will "fail" the divisibility test and get incremented that way.)

```
ＩＬ↨Πυ²
```

Output the length of the base `2` representation of the product.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(i=s=p=1;n;s*=j?1:n--&&i)for(j=i++;s*i<2?i%j--:[++p,s/=2];)p")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoMgFAX3noIYa6CUtroUfz1I00RisYGQDxHjxnh2iqt5mTdWbSpOiwmrQP/VaYaE8NKbcrSc/UINRAjQSJTxCnZoOhSirg07PwuG8@xN3w7mYoXo3pyHW3xA@5EslCydldMrQQKkkRk9kPaZB@eM7AUhk8fonb47/6OjotWOB8tttc8U2TEyWRzpDw)

Little RAM. Assumes n#(Product of first n primes) don't get too near to \$2^k\$ and therefore need confirm.

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 73 bytes basically by Arnauld

```javascript
n=>eval("for(p=k=i=1n;n;d?0:p*=n--&&k)for(d=k++;k%d--;);for(;p/=2n;)++i")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoMwEETvfkUQK9mGtNZjt9v@isHEYhM2QcWL@O2pnmZ4b5ifWc3cT2NaNEfr8kCZ6e1WE2Q5xEkm8jTSg5HRfppnuhJrXdceTmnJK4X@YrVGwJNgulPLCEqNJeSTBLcIFiSOiyNfJNrmbEqB2Aoh@shzDO4W4ld2RlYb73Csq22QDHsHWOz5Dw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda N,P=1,p=1:len(-N*f"{P:b}")or f(N-P**p%-~p,P-P**p%~p*P,p+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ndNscxJzk1ISFfx0AmwNdQpsDa1yUvM0dP200pSqA6ySapU084sU0jT8dAO0tApUdesKdAIgzLoCrQCdAm1DTahR-mlAhVUKmXkKRYl56akahgaaVgVFmXklGkCTqmoVNKqrtA1rNRWq0zSqNIHGQrTBXAIA)

Disclaimer: This one has one flaw which is that it is "zero-based" which is stretching the rules, I suppose. But I'd still very much like to show it off.

Obviousy, this is heavily based on @dingledooper's answer.

### How?

This leverages a bit of elementary number theory, i.e. Fermat's little theorem, to squeeze out a few bytes.

The basic strategy is the same as dingledooper's: Use the nascent primorial to identify the next prime.What we do differently is when testing the next prime number candidate \$p\$ we raise the primorial \$P\$ to one less power, \$P^{p-1}\mod p\$ instead of \$P^p \mod p\$ That way we know the value can only be \$1\$ (iff \$p\$ is indeed a prime) or \$0\$. The value can, for example, directly be used to decrement the prime number counter. The conditional update of the primorial is also streamlined.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 45 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb898nNS@9JMPBM68kNT21yCUzPbOkODokMze12MEhoAhI1zkWFSVW1inrGMWq/U9T0HdQCErMS0@NNtRRMDKIVdDXB6rKK/kPAA)

```
Length@IntegerDigits[Times@@Prime~Array~#,2]&
```