# How many trailing zeros in the hyperfactorial?

Tags: code-golf, factorial

We have a challenge to [calculate the hyperfactorial](/q/235964/39490) and one to [count the trailing zeros of the factorial](/q/79762/39490), so it seems logical to put them together and count the trailing zeros in the hyperfactorial.

As a recap, the [hyperfactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfactorial) of a number, H(n) is simply Πiⁱ, that is, 1¹·2²·3³·4⁴·5⁵·…·nⁿ.  It can be defined recursively as H(n) = nⁿH(n-1) with H(0) = 1.  This is integer sequence [A002109](https://oeis.org/A002109).

Your task is to write the shortest program or function that accepts a non-negative integer `n` and returns or prints the number of trailing zeros in H(`n`) when represented as a decimal number (i.e. the corresponding entry from sequence [A246839](https://oeis.org/A246839)).

`n` will be in the range of integers in your language; H(`n`) might not be.  That means your **program must terminate** given any non-negative `n` that's valid in your language (or 2³² if that's smaller).

Some test cases:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 10 | 15 |
| 24 | 50 |
| 25 | 100 |
| 250 | 8125 |
| 10000 | 12518750 |

Comment: Suggest not including \$0^0\$ as it's undefined somewhere

Comment: Okay, but H(0) is still 1, just like 0! is 1.

Comment: After having just looked at [Number of bits needed to represent the product of the first primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/263531), it took me several minutes to realize this question was about base-10 trailing zeros, not `__builtin_ctz( h )`, the number of trailing zero *bits*.  (Which would be the sum of the ctz of each input times its power, I think.)  Base 10 explains all the `5`s in the answers! :P

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and(f(m:=n//5)-m*~m//2)*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCsMgEEbhfU4xyxmZoLERSiAnCV1YgjRQ/4hk002vbnx8q1d@1@fE41lqa2n9xvzeI2EBReycOC8rrA0yZvPP1noxoZV64GKzMTQxRNJZCXSABnY66axBJ6d@Vh@6vlxPXtJu)

### How?

Calculates the number almost directly only recursing to correct for higher powers of 5 in the base:

$$\begin{align}
f(n) & =\sum_{i=5,10,...,n} i+\sum_{i=25,50,...,n}i+\sum_{i=125,250,...,n}i+... \\ & =5 \sum_{i=1}^\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor i + 25 \sum_{i=1}^\left\lfloor\frac n {25} \right\rfloor i + 125 \sum_{i=1}^\left\lfloor\frac n {125} \right\rfloor i + ... \\ & = 5 \sum_{i=1}^\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor i + 5 f\left(\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor\right) \\ & = 5 \frac{\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor+1\right)}2 + 5 f\left(\left\lfloor\frac n 5 \right\rfloor\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Great description - thank you!

Comment: Is there not a released 3.8 yet?  Or is the pre-release somehow more capable?

Comment: @TobySpeight Neither I believe, TIO just happens to be stuck on that version. Python official is at 3.11 or so.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&f(~-n)+g(n)*n
g=n=>n%5?0:-~g(n/5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i5PTS1No043T1M7XSNPUyuPKx0sqmpqb2ClWwcU0zfV/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYaCpyYUqYoIhYoohYoipzQhTn5EpFiEDLIYBgabmfwA)

-3 bytes from Arnauld

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&f(n=n/5|0)*5-n*~n/2*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i5PTS1NI882T9@0xkBTy1Q3T6suT99Iy/R/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaBpiYXqogJhogphoghpjYjTH1GpliEDLAYBgSamv8B)

Port of loopy walt's

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and f(n-1)+g(n)*n
g=lambda i:i%5<1and-~g(i/5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvLCsIwEEX3/YoBETKValPMokU/ptqHA82kJNNFN/56rItiHLhwLvfMvMrLcRXJzs4LhDVkW86hF98/Fx/I8USWROkyz2uMw31q7aNrgRuGljsYFBcaT6NizDkb95kaOpqb3oziPSq6GIyzJxY1qBIx2/masElYp1KVWpX5K1/vAL@37RChACHbB3CLxA8)

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and(f(n/5)-n/5*~(n/5)/2)*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvBCsMgDIbvfQqPRlhrZR5W6MO4tWWBGkXTQy97dSeDgQ0kfD/5/njyO5Ap6GNILPKZu7p9XjmtryNlDLSjR5ajVuoBZZt355@LEzSRcLTITdJg4VaP@vxwMKBsiQmJ61MDdH@@N2wbHlvJtJaxl6AvpToA5Qs)

Port of loopy walt's Python answer.

Comment: This seems to struggle with the medium-sized test cases I've recently added.  Remember that input is any valid non-negative!

Comment: @TobySpeight that was just the recursion limit - I've updated the link.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＩΣＥ⊕Ｎ×ι⌕⮌Ｘ⁰↨ι⁵¦⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoMwEEWvkuUEUhDBlbsWCl0o0nqBMQ40YKJMEj3@GP2r93jf/pHtiovIwC4keGFM8MseOtzgEyyTp5BoLrzl1Gc/EYPWRo3OUwRn1NuFGb60E0eCYT1Kr4x6YrFSG32dK32vFakbeezLCQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ               Input integer
   ⊕                Incremented
  Ｅ                 Map over implicit (inclusive) range
      ι             Current value
     ×              Times
          ⁰         Literal integer `0`
         Ｘ          Vectorised raise to power
            ι       Current value
           ↨        Converted to base
             ⁵      Literal integer `5`
        ⮌           Reversed
       ⌕            Find index of
               ⁰    Literal integer `0`
 Σ                  Take the sum
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: Does this work with the full range of positive integers?

Comment: @TobySpeight Probably only up to python's `sys.maxsize` as Charcoal doesn't use generators.

Comment: That's reasonable - at first I thought this computed H(n), which would make the full range too expensive.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
g(n){n=n%5?0:-~g(n/5);}f(n){n=n?f(~-n)+g(n)*n:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbboMwDH3vV1hISEkJKrBF68pYH6Z9xeABhYShbaEikYaG6KePmUtRu0i27JNzTmILvxRiGEqiaacT7fJjcPDP2O44jXu1wEdFzr6m3kjb6kMQ90OlLXzllSYUug3gGQErjX3LIIEuYHDPgDMIsYqwjPgYwQjg6eNVI9uTFFYWqy6YdRgLncE@HOWYwv0Dv4hFrY0F8Z43W8xSfMhm9nDS9jVK28cXDO4wuO7vnEWt6gbI@H6lC9miLIiX8glM9SNrRS4/o7sF2K5IDJ43selkNm9g3QK6TZuYGFl8c2nwUhFLb1GJ6LqI/7JTgxRFHLcA/xkwuybVOJdlYNg6OlokYLLFuN/0w69Qn3lpBv/7Dw)

*Port of [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2) [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263600/9481)*

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 30 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,n,i*valuation(i,5))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW-_J07YpLczUybQ118nQytcoSc0oTSzLz8zQydUw1NSGKbjonFhTkVGrkKejaKRQUZeaVAJlKII6SQppGnqamjkK0gY6CiY6CqY6CIZBlBGSaANlGpgYgASCIhRq1YAGEBgA)

Based on Michel Marcus's code on the OEIS page.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 31 bytes

*port of loopy walt's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263606/112488).*

```c
f(n){n=n?(f(n/=5)-n*~n/2)*5:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLasMwELz7KwZDQEpk/GhE07puD6VfkfgQFDkVbeVgGWpq3E@vu1ESJws77Aw7i0Yq2is1jhWzvLeFfWE0xYXkkZ3/2jjjc/mY5MNobBt8bY1lPOgDUJFA2GrXrksU6BOBpYAUSGnKaEQmPRClShOqQXgroLuDVq3eTdbkZKU@7tOywCo9HiBIV/fyajUCrYAT0LlXVG1dC/W@bQi0@tDNulwv/d1w071lm@7hlVqGArf8LhxO/qpuwAytJzkMnuDMj64rdgzG4zOZe5ZjsTAc/fkhFJ5c/gNMmU@iI5Hs/KpoUqbAt6uHhj6xYuFM7hA9Y7bDzG1seAl4iUP@Aq48XxyCYfxT1ed278bo@x8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 34 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.25 bytes

```
ɾ:5Ǒ*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBPXMiLCIiLCLJvjo1x5EqIiwiIiwiNVxuMTBcbjI0XG4yNSJd)

-7 bits thanks to emanresu

### Explained

```
ɾ:5Ǒ*­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
ɾ      # ‎⁡The range [1, input]
 :     # ‎⁢Duplicated
  5Ǒ   # ‎⁣With the multiplicity of 5 of each number
    *  # ‎⁤Multiply that by the original list
# ‎⁢⁡The s flag sums the list
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [39 bits and O(n)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBPSIsIiIsIsm+OjXHkSriiJEiLCIiLCI1XG4xMFxuMjRcbjI1Il0=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ọ€5ḋR
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer, \$n\$, and yields the number of trailing zeros of the hyperfactorial, \$H(n)\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7t5HTWtMH@7oDvr//7@hARAAAA)**

#### How?

As the hyperfactorial's input increases, each time \$n\$ reaches a multiple of five [\$n\nu_5(n)\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) more zeros are added.

```
ọ€5ḋR - Link: non-negative integer, n
 €    - for each {i in [1..n]}:
ọ 5   -   {i} order of multiplicity of {5}
    R - range {n} -> [1..n]
   ḋ  - dot-product
```

Comment: I guess `Rọ5ḋƊ` also works?

Comment: Yep, or even the no hyper (`€ⱮÞ"...`), no quick (`$Ɗ¥?Ƈ...`) `Rọ5ḋR`

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 47 bytes

```
f(k)=∑_{n=1}^knlog_5(gcd(n,5^{ceil(log_5n)}))
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tmk6nq0lyo)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ijoz3m8l5y)

It can be `f(k)=∑_{n=1}^knlog_5(gcd(n,5^n))` but that quickly runs into inaccuracies even for smaller inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LDmTªPγθg<
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@lyxal*.

Actually calculates \$H(n)\$ and counts the amount of trailing 0s, so this is a much slower approach. Still valid though, since the new 05AB1E is built in Elixir, which has an infinitely large integer and is only limited by memory (in the legacy version of 05AB1E, built in Python, it would be valid as well for the same reason).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxyU35NCqgHObz@1It/n/38jUAAA) or [verify (almost) all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H5fckEOrAs5tPrcj3ea/zv9oAx0THVMdQwMdIxMdI1MgMtAxNTCIBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L           # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 D          # Duplicate it
  m         # Take the power of the values at the same positions: [1**1,2**2,3**3,...]
   Tª       # Append a 10 to this list
     P      # Take the product
      γ     # Group adjacent equal digits together in substrings
       θ    # Pop and keep the trailing part of 0s
        g   # Pop and push its length
         <  # And decrease it by 1
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The `Tª` and `<` are only there for inputs in the range \$0\leq n<4\$. For \$n\geq5\$ it works fine without it. These three bytes also have loads of alternatives (i.e. [`LDmP0«γθ¦g`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H5fcAINDq89tPrfj0LL0/zr/ow10THRMdQwNdIxMdIxMgchAx9TAIBYA); [`LDmPγθgDi0`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H5fcgHObz@1Id8k0@F@r8z/aQMdEx1TH0EDHyETHyBSIDHRMDQxiAQ); [`LDmPγθgD≠*`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H5fcgHObz@1Id3nUuUDrv87/aAMdEx1THUMDHSMTHSNTIDLQMTUwiAUA); etc.), but I've been unable to find anything shorter thus far.

#### Original <s>16</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:

```
ƒNÐ5sm¿5.n*O
```

Port of [*AidenChow*'s Desmos answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263619/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2CS/wxNMi3MP7TfVy9Py///fyNQAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Y5P8Dk8wLc49tN9UL0/L/3@tzv9oAx0THVMdQwMdIxMdI1MgMgBygCAWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ƒ             # Loop `N` in the range [0, (implicit) input-integer]:
 NÐ           #  Push three copies of `N` to the stack
 N 5sm        #  Pop one, and push 5 to the power `N`
 N    ¿       #  Pop this and another `N`, and push their Greatest Common Divisor
       5.n    #  Take log_5 of that value
 N        *   #  Multiply it by the remaining `N`
           O  #  Sum all values on the stack together
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

05AB1E lacks the convenient `multiplicity`-builtin that the Jelly and Vyxal answers have, <s>although I still have the feeling this can be shorter with another approach, since the `5sm` and `5.n` are rather verbose.</s> EDIT: which was indeed correct.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxyU3wODQar1zm2vP7Ti0LP3/fyNTAwA "05AB1E – Try It Online") for 12 bytes using a different approach (group by)

Comment: @lyxal 10 bytes actually, since `.γ}` is basically builtin `γ`. :) Thanks!

Comment: Heh i tried searching the docs for group by consecutive and only found the digraph. I figured you'd manage to sneak in some obscure 05ab1e knowledge I wouldn't have known :p

Comment: Doesn’t Python use arbitrary large integers?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Ah, you're completely right. Edited my post above. Thanks for noticing. :)

Comment: Heh I think this is like the first time someone has ported one of my Desmos answers, and I certainly didn’t expect it from a golfing lang. Cool!

Comment: Just a note, in my desmos answer, I had to do `5^{ceil(log_5n)}` because of some floating point inaccuracies, but I think if your lang has arbitrary precision then you can simply do `5^n`. Not that it changes much now that you are using another strategy.

Comment: @AidenChow Hmm, I did try your bottom formula with my original answer, but was getting incorrect results before.  But I likely did something else wrong, since they're indeed correct now, so I've modified the bottom answer to this shorter 12-byter, which as you expected, is indeed still slightly longer than my top 10-bytes approach.

Comment: Yea the only difference between the two is that instead of calculating something like `gcd(10000,5^10000)` which desmos freaks out on, it calculates `gcd(10000,5^6)` which is much more manageable. But in theory `gcd(n,5^n)` works completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 68 bytes

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(A1),IFERROR(SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(PRODUCT(a^a),,0)="")),))
```

Input in cell `A1`. Fails for `A1>7`.

Comment: 8 is a valid input, so this isn't a correct answer.  I've edited the question to make it clearer that it has to work for _all_ valid inputs.

Comment: Ah, so there is no tolerance for IEEE 754 precision errors? You expect a solution to handle all inputs up to and including 10,000?

Comment: Up to 2³² if that's a number in your language.

Comment: AFAIK, Excel only has 15-bit precision floating-point numbers. Here's a link to the specs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EDHBBFDBD

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 47 bytes

```
.+
$*¶

$.`$*#$.`$*
+%`^(#+)\1{4}\b
$'¶$1
A`#
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0Xr0DYuLhW9BBUtZTDJpa2aEKehrK0ZY1htUhuTxKWifmibiiGXY4Iyl@H//wZcJlymXIYGXEYmXEamQGQAAA) Link includes Link includes faster test cases (since it calculates in unary internally, it times out TIO after about `3000` and probably runs out of memory anyway after about `30000`). Explanation:

```
.+
$*¶

$.`$*#$.`$*
```

Generate a range from `0` up to and including the input, in duplicated unary, once using `#` and once using `1`.

```
%`^(#+)\1{4}\b
$'¶$1
```

For each entry that has a multiple of `5` `#`s, remove them leaving the `1`s, and then append an entry with the number of `#`s divided by `5`, but with the original number of `1`s.

```
+`
```

Repeatedly process any new entries that have a multiple of `5` `#`s.

```
A`#
```

Remove all entries that weren't a multiple of `5` `#`s. (If they were, the `#`s would have been removed.)

```
1
```

Count the number of trailing zeros.

Retina 1 can do the whole calculation in decimal, allowing it to quickly compute the result for `10000`, although it does take 65 bytes:

```
.+
*¶

$.`
+%`.*50*$
$.(*2*
~["L$`^¶$.("|""L$rm`0*$
$.($:&*$&)$*_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0vr0DYuLhW9BC5t1QQ9LVMDLRUgT0PLSIurLlrJRyUh7tA2IF@pRgnIKcpNgMqrWKlpqahpqmjF//9vwGXCZcplaMBlZMJlZApEBkAOEAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*¶

$.`,$.`
```

Generate a range from `0` up to and including the input.

```
+%`.*50*$
$.(*2*
```

Double any value that ends in 5, 50, 500 etc. as many times as necessary so that it does not.

```
["L$`^¶$.("|""L$rm`0*$
$.($:&*$&)$*_
```

Multiply each original value by the number of trailing zeros, then generate a command that calculates the sum of those products. The intermediate multiplication allows use of a capture on the right which would otherwise have to be wrapped. The match is performed right-to-left so that values with trailing zeros are only matched once but matches without trailing zeros are also matched so that the match index will give the original value.

```
~`
```

Execute that command.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 48 bytes

Port of [@loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263606/110802) in Scala.

```scala
n=>{if(n<1)0 else{val m=n/5;(f(m)+m*(m+1)/2)*5}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU_LSsNAFN3nK46li5k2pUk0ILEpuBR0Ja6ki2nNlJHMrcxMBQnzJW6yUfCT-jfemDpw3_ecc-fz2-9Uqy7708Vh-9rsAh6UIXRJAryrFrq6o1Cv2aH-Oga9uD5lVK87owWtcpmhaX3TDZu2pmV5I7Swcm5nws5zuSzkrIzxjPsBXhoNy_xCub2vcOuc-nh-DM7QfiMrPJFhGRYHRnU62m3jPPfujQ8iS5GnuEpRcsJFwWlRDjZMMn7yD6oPDoKwWvwTyDMn8MZaQfiJmFKKace_kFFiMuJiMlhMxoP7foy_)